# How to import existing Git repository into another?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have a Git repository in a folder called **XXX**, and I have second Git repository called **YYY**.

I want to import the **XXX** repository into the **YYY** repository as a subdirectory named **ZZZ** and add all **XXX**'s change history to **YYY**.

Folder structure before:

```
├── XXX
│   ├── .git
│   └── (project files)
└── YYY
    ├── .git
    └── (project files)
```

Folder structure after:

```
YYY
├── .git  <-- This now contains the change history from XXX
├──  ZZZ  <-- This was originally XXX
│    └── (project files)
└──  (project files)
```

Can this be done, or must I resort to using sub-modules?

Comment: On Github it's now possible to do this from the web interface when you create a new repo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you merge two git repositories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Comment: @bgcode comment was really useful for me - thanks.  You can import another repo straight from GitHub's UI and saves a ton of work

Answer (score 509, accepted):

Probably the simplest way would be to pull the **XXX** stuff into a branch in **YYY** and then merge it into master:

In **YYY**:

```
git remote add other /path/to/XXX
git fetch other
git checkout -b ZZZ other/master
mkdir ZZZ
git mv stuff ZZZ/stuff                      # repeat as necessary for each file/dir
git commit -m "Moved stuff to ZZZ"
git checkout master                
git merge ZZZ --allow-unrelated-histories   # should add ZZZ/ to master
git commit
git remote rm other
git branch -d ZZZ                           # to get rid of the extra branch before pushing
git push                                    # if you have a remote, that is
```

I actually just tried this with a couple of my repos and it works. Unlike [Jörg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another/1684435#1684435) it won't let you continue to use the other repo, but I don't think you specified that anyway.

Note: Since this was originally written in 2009, git has added the subtree merge mentioned in the answer below. I would probably use that method today, although of course this method does still work.

Comment: Thanks.  I used a slightly modified version of your technique: I created a 'staging' branch on XXX where I created the ZZZ folder, and moved the 'stuff' into it.  Then I merged XXX into YYY.

Comment: This worked great for me.  The only changes I made were:

1) "git branch -d ZZZ" before the push because I didn't want this temp branch hanging around.

2) "git push" was giving me the error: "No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing. Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'." (The origin I was pushing to was an empty bare repository.)  But "git push --all" worked like a champ.

Comment: I don’t see any reason why you can’t continue to use the other repository. It seems to be possible to merge changes from the other repository provided you use `git merge -s subtree`.

Comment: I wanted to end up with only the ZZZ folder plus history in the YYY repo: I wanted to delete the original XXX repo, and the ZZZ branch in the YYY repo. I found deleting the ZZZ branch as @CrazyPyro suggested removed the history — to keep it I merged the ZZZ branch into master before deleting.

Comment: Is it just me, or does this solution not preserve the history? I tried it with one file and after checkout of master, the file appears only as added. After the commit, I have only that one in the history. The result is the same as if I had added the file through copy paste and manual add.

Comment: @SebastianBlask I've done this multiple times and it does preserve the history — that's the whole point of using the remotes, etc.

Comment: @ebneter: maybe it doesn't work anymore or something is missing? I am using git version 1.7.10.4... after git mv, git status says "renamed:    stuff -> ZZZ/stuff" but then after checkout of master: "new file:   ZZZ/stuff" after the commit, git log only gives this this commit and git blame doesn't show anything but the last commit either.

Comment: @SebastianBlask I just messed around with this with two of my repos, and realized that there is a missing step that no one has ever seemed to notice, despite my getting upvotes on this for years. :-) I _mentioned_ merging it into master, but didn't actually show it. Editing it now...

Comment: Is there a way to do this without involving a git mv command? For example, so history is preserved in the "git log" command without using the --follow argument.

Comment: @Danra I don't believe so — you are changing the location of files, so there's no way around that. You could use ColinM's subtree merge solution below but I'm not sure what the history looks like in the log as I have never done it.

Comment: Thanks for this.  We've just been been through this, but we wanted to bring two branches with us, ZZZ our tracking branch, and AAA a branch of ZZZ.  It took us a while.  Here are my condensed notes: 1) before removing the remote, while in `./YYY` directory `git checkout -b AAA origin/AAA`, 2) switch to YYY and `git fetch`, 3) bring over other branch with `git checkout -b AAA other/AAA`, 4) merge the ported branches `git merge`.  _(Watch the movie Inception to prepare your mind for the necessary Gitfoo)_

Comment: you could add something like this, when moving files to your subfolder: 

`git mv $(ls|grep -v <your foldername>) <your foldername>/`

This will copy all files and folders into your new folder

Comment: It works as expected, however each time I move around files in the other repository, the merge  fails  with `both deleted ../../*, added by us, by them`. `-Xtheirs` doesn't really change anything, anyone knows how to make the content of ZZZ folder to follow original files location and rename/move files accordingly?

Comment: Is it possible to link to the subtree merge answer? ("Below" changes over time)

Comment: I wouldn't be so easily swayed towards using `git subtree`. The downside is that the merged history is unchaged (not in a subdirectory). More on subtree merges [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/8ad01701db51ec2891ca431b78c58c72#file-4-2-sh). Although your solution has this very problem, that can be [avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62104099/52499). Feel free to borrow from my answer.

Comment: @VijayPatel please reconsider your accepted answer, I think x-yuri's is the winner as it maintains history perfectly and doesn't require multiple `git mv` commands: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4142653/67824

Answer (score 405):

If you want to retain the exact commit history of the second repository and therefore also retain the ability to easily merge upstream changes in the future then here is the method you want. It results in unmodified history of the subtree being imported into your repo plus one merge commit to move the merged repository to the subdirectory.

```
git remote add XXX_remote <path-or-url-to-XXX-repo>
git fetch XXX_remote
git merge -s ours --no-commit --allow-unrelated-histories XXX_remote/master
git read-tree --prefix=ZZZ/ -u XXX_remote/master
git commit -m "Imported XXX as a subtree."
```

You can track upstream changes like so:

```
git pull -s subtree XXX_remote master
```

Git figures out on its own where the roots are before doing the merge, so you don't need to specify the prefix on subsequent merges.

The **downside** is that in the merged history the files are unprefixed (not in a subdirectory). As a result `git log ZZZ/a` will show you all the changes (if any) except those in the merged history. You can do:

```
git log --follow -- a
```

but that won't show the changes other then in the merged history.

In other words, if you don't change `ZZZ`'s files in repository `XXX`, then you need to specify `--follow` and an unprefixed path. If you change them in both repositories, then you have 2 commands, none of which shows all the changes.

**Git versions before 2.9**: You don’t need to pass the `--allow-unrelated-histories` option to `git merge`.

The method in the other answer that uses `read-tree` and skips the `merge -s ours` step is effectively no different than copying the files with cp and committing the result.

Original source was from [github's "Subtree Merge" help article](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/about-git-subtree-merges). And [another useful link](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/8ad01701db51ec2891ca431b78c58c72#file-4-2-sh).

Comment: this doesn't seem to have preserved history... if I do a `git log` on any of the files I pulled in I just see the single merge commit and nothing from its previous life in the other repo? Git 1.8.0

Comment: hmm, on the other hand I do see commits from the imported repo if I just `git log` at the root level, so its a limitation of how I was trying to view the history of imported files - is there a way?

Comment: aha! if I use the old path of the imported file, i.e. omit the subdir it's been imported into, then git log will give me the commit history, eg `git log -- myfile` instead of `git log -- rack/myfile`

Comment: Using git pull as you said, has imported the logs in my master. What can I do?

Comment: @FrancescoFrassinelli, isn't that desirable? Bringing the history in is a *feature* of this method.

Comment: @patrickvacek It became difficult to browse the history and I'm not interested in my project dependencies history.

Comment: @FrancescoFrassinelli, if you don't want history, why not just do a regular copy? I'm trying to figure out what would draw you to this method if not for the history -- that's the only reason I used this method!

Comment: @patrickvacek I was looking for a clean way to have dependencies. Maybe there are better solution for my kind of problem (I'm not git expert).

Comment: @FrancescoFrassinelli Have you tried the "--follow" option of "git log"?

Comment: An alternative link, referenced from the Github link: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html   It contains some more explanation and reasoning, and is a little easier to follow than Github's example.

Comment: You can find this information in here https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-subtree-merge

Comment: Great solution, it works great. I would just add another comment if you wish to merge two repositories but the second will be merge into the first (no new parent repository) replace the read-tree line with: git read-tree -mu rack_remote/master- it means that the second repository will be merge to the first.

Comment: If this solution is used, is it safe to delete the rack repository after the merge is completed?

Comment: @AlexBrooks I assume you mean the "remote" since there is only one repo involved. It is safe, although you probably won't be saving much space by doing so since the commits that were merged will remain in your repo. That is, all of your own commits and the merged commits live in the same repo after this operation.

Comment: @ColinM So I mean if I merge repo `A` into repo `B` with this method, is it then safe to completely delete repo `A`?

Comment: If you omit the explicit merge, this should replace submodules forever.

Comment: Since Git 2.9, you need the option `--allow-unrelated-histories` when doing the merge.

Comment: This works great, thanks. Any chance of not importing the tags from the other repository?

Comment: @Anentropic Regarding the history, this link seems to be provide some way of rewriting the history so that the paths point to the new subdirectory. Haven't yet tried this, so I'm not sure if it works: https://gofore.com/merge-multiple-git-repositories-one-retaining-history/

Comment: I love this; the only change I'd suggest is to flag arbitrary option values as, well, arbitrary. I assumed "rack" was a keyword and so on.

Comment: @FrancescoFrassinelli Should this keep the history tab in bitbucket up-to-date? Or is the most important concern preserving the git log history? I see the git log showing all past commits and bitbucket also shows the history via the "Blame" button but when I actually go into the history tab in the repo on bitbucket itself I only see my recent merge..I'm thinking the history tab is related to that file only??

Comment: Can I add patches on top of XXX/ZZZ? What happens to git pull if I had patches in this subfolder?

Comment: @vvassilev You can both modify your imported subtree and merge updates from the upstream. When you merge the upstream changes the conflicts will be resolved like any other merge.

Answer (score 176):

[`git-subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt) is a script designed for exactly this use case of merging multiple repositories into one while preserving history (and/or splitting history of subtrees, though that seems to be irrelevant to this question). It is distributed as part of the git tree [since release 1.7.11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/634392b26275fe5436c0ea131bc89b46476aa4ae).

To merge a repository `<repo>` at revision `<rev>` as subdirectory `<prefix>`, use `git subtree add` as follows:

```
git subtree add -P <prefix> <repo> <rev>
```

git-subtree implements the [subtree merge strategy](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_subtree_merge) in a more user friendly manner.

For your case, inside repository YYY, you would run:

```
git subtree add -P ZZZ /path/to/XXX.git master
```

The **downside** is that in the merged history the files are unprefixed (not in a subdirectory). As a result `git log ZZZ/a` will show you all the changes (if any) except those in the merged history. You can do:

```
git log --follow -- a
```

but that won't show the changes other then in the merged history.

In other words, if you don't change `ZZZ`'s files in repository `XXX`, then you need to specify `--follow` and an unprefixed path. If you change them in both repositories, then you have 2 commands, none of which shows all the changes.

More on it [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/8ad01701db51ec2891ca431b78c58c72#file-4-2-sh).

Comment: If you have a directory to merge instead of a bare repository or remote, `git subtree add -P name-of-desired-prefix ~/location/of/git/repo-without-.git branch-name`

Comment: Noob experience: git (version 2.9.0.windows.1) responds "fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree" when I tried this in a freshly initialised, local, non-bare repository,  But it worked fine after I _really_ got the new repository going, i.e. after adding a plain file and committing the regular way.

Answer (score 52):

There is a well-known instance of this in the Git repository itself, which is collectively known in the Git community as "[the coolest merge ever](http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0506/5511.html)" (after the subject line Linus Torvalds used in the e-mail to the Git mailinglist which describes this merge). In this case, the `gitk` Git GUI which now is part of Git proper, actually used to be a separate project. Linus managed to merge that repository into the Git repository in a way that

- it appears in the Git repository as if it had always been developed as part of Git,
- all the history is kept intact and
- it can still be developed independently in its old repository, with changes simply being `git pull`ed.

The e-mail contains the steps needed to reproduce, but it is not for the faint of heart: first, Linus *wrote* Git, so he probably knows a bit more about it than you or me, and second, this was almost 5 years ago and Git has improved *considerably* since then, so maybe it is now much easier.

In particular, I guess nowadays one would use a gitk submodule, in that specific case.

Comment: BTW. the strategy used for subsequent merges (if there are any) is called **subtree** merge, and there is third party `git-subtree` tool which can help you with this: http://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that. The `subtree` merge strategy, especially in conjunction with the `git-subtree` tool is a nice, maybe even superior alternative to submodules.

Comment: That link was broken for me; this one works (for now): https://marc.info/?l=git&m=111947722514210&w=2

Answer (score 20):

Let me use names `a` (in place of `XXX` and `ZZZ`) and `b` (in place of `YYY`), since that makes the description a bit easier to read.

Say you want to merge repository `a` into `b` (I'm assuming they're located alongside one another):

```
cd a
git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter a
cd ..
cd b
git remote add a ../a
git fetch a
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories a/master
git remote remove a
```

For this you need [`git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) installed (`filter-branch` is [discouraged](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning)).

An example of merging 2 big repositories, putting one of them into a subdirectory: https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/9890ab1079cf4357d6f269d073fd9731

More on it [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/6161d90d1af8ebac6e560bcef548c1c3).

Comment: Excellent. History appears in `git log` without issues, unlike the solution with `git subtree add -P ...`.

Comment: The one thing the original requester wanted was XXX to be in a folder ZZZ.  Hence the 'git mv stuff ZZZ/stuff` command.  i don't see how your solution addresses that requirement.

Comment: @Jim the subfolder part is taken care of by `filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter`, see https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html. Just used this method myself, worked perfectly (since I'm on Windows, had to fix the PATH per https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html)

Answer (score 14):

The simple way to do that is to use git format-patch.

Assume we have 2 git repositories **foo** and **bar**.

**foo** contains:

- foo.txt
- .git

**bar** contains:

- bar.txt
- .git

and we want to end-up with **foo** containing the **bar** history and these files:

- foo.txt
- .git
- foobar/bar.txt

So to do that:

```
 1. create a temporary directory eg PATH_YOU_WANT/patch-bar
 2. go in bar directory
 3. git format-patch --root HEAD --no-stat -o PATH_YOU_WANT/patch-bar --src-prefix=a/foobar/ --dst-prefix=b/foobar/
 4. go in foo directory
 5. git am PATH_YOU_WANT/patch-bar/*
```

And if we want to rewrite all message commits from bar we can do, eg on Linux:

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter 'sed "1s/^/\[bar\] /"' COMMIT_SHA1_OF_THE_PARENT_OF_THE_FIRST_BAR_COMMIT..HEAD
```

This will add "[bar] " at the beginning of each commit message.

Comment: If the original repository contained branches and merges, `git am` will likely fail.

Comment: Minor gotcha: git am strips anything in `[ ]` from the commit message. So you should use a different marker than `[bar]`

Comment: Did not work for me. Got "error: foobar/mySubDir/test_host1: does not exist in index. The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   /home/myuser/src/proj/.git/rebase-apply/patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue". This was after applying 11 patches (out of 60).

Comment: [This blog](http://blog.neutrino.es/2012/git-copy-a-file-or-directory-from-another-repository-preserving-history/) has a similar answer to a somewhat different question (moving only selected files).

Comment: I see one disadvantage, all commits are added to the HEAD of the target repository.

Answer (score 10):

This function will clone remote repo into local repo dir, after merging all commits will be saved, `git log` will be show the original commits and proper paths:

```
function git-add-repo
{
    repo="$1"
    dir="$(echo "$2" | sed 's/\/$//')"
    path="$(pwd)"

    tmp="$(mktemp -d)"
    remote="$(echo "$tmp" | sed 's/\///g'| sed 's/\./_/g')"

    git clone "$repo" "$tmp"
    cd "$tmp"

    git filter-branch --index-filter '
        git ls-files -s |
        sed "s,\t,&'"$dir"'/," |
        GIT_INDEX_FILE="$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" git update-index --index-info &&
        mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
    ' HEAD

    cd "$path"
    git remote add -f "$remote" "file://$tmp/.git"
    git pull "$remote/master"
    git merge --allow-unrelated-histories -m "Merge repo $repo into master" --edit "$remote/master"
    git remote remove "$remote"
    rm -rf "$tmp"
}
```

How to use:

```
cd current/package
git-add-repo https://github.com/example/example dir/to/save
```

If make a little changes you can even move files/dirs of merged repo into different paths, for example:

```
repo="https://github.com/example/example"
path="$(pwd)"

tmp="$(mktemp -d)"
remote="$(echo "$tmp" | sed 's/\///g' | sed 's/\./_/g')"

git clone "$repo" "$tmp"
cd "$tmp"

GIT_ADD_STORED=""

function git-mv-store
{
    from="$(echo "$1" | sed 's/\./\\./')"
    to="$(echo "$2" | sed 's/\./\\./')"

    GIT_ADD_STORED+='s,\t'"$from"',\t'"$to"',;'
}

# NOTICE! This paths used for example! Use yours instead!
git-mv-store 'public/index.php' 'public/admin.php'
git-mv-store 'public/data' 'public/x/_data'
git-mv-store 'public/.htaccess' '.htaccess'
git-mv-store 'core/config' 'config/config'
git-mv-store 'core/defines.php' 'defines/defines.php'
git-mv-store 'README.md' 'doc/README.md'
git-mv-store '.gitignore' 'unneeded/.gitignore'

git filter-branch --index-filter '
    git ls-files -s |
    sed "'"$GIT_ADD_STORED"'" |
    GIT_INDEX_FILE="$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" git update-index --index-info &&
    mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
' HEAD

GIT_ADD_STORED=""

cd "$path"
git remote add -f "$remote" "file://$tmp/.git"
git pull "$remote/master"
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories -m "Merge repo $repo into master" --edit "$remote/master"
git remote remove "$remote"
rm -rf "$tmp"
```

**Notices**
Paths replaces via `sed`, so make sure it moved in proper paths after merging.
The `--allow-unrelated-histories` parameter only exists since git >= 2.9.

Comment: For OS X folks out there, install `gnu-sed` to get the `git-add-repo` function working. Thanks again Andrey!

Answer (score 7):

Based [on this article](http://bneijt.nl/blog/post/merge-a-subdirectory-of-another-repository-with-git/), using subtree is what worked for me and only applicable history was transferred.  Posting here in case anyone needs the steps (make sure to replace the placeholders with values applicable to you):

in your source repository split subfolder into a new branch

`git subtree split --prefix=<source-path-to-merge> -b subtree-split-result`

in your destination repo merge in the split result branch

```
git remote add merge-source-repo <path-to-your-source-repository>
git fetch merge-source-repo
git merge -s ours --no-commit merge-source-repo/subtree-split-result
git read-tree --prefix=<destination-path-to-merge-into> -u merge-source-repo/subtree-split-result
```

verify your changes and commit

```
git status
git commit
```

Don't forget to

Clean up by deleting the `subtree-split-result` branch

`git branch -D subtree-split-result`

Remove the remote you added to fetch the data from source repo

`git remote rm merge-source-repo`

Answer (score 3):

Adding another answer as I think this is a bit simpler. A pull of repo_dest is done into repo_to_import and then a push --set-upstream url:repo_dest master is done.

This method has worked for me importing several smaller repos into a bigger one.

How to import: repo1_to_import to repo_dest

```
# checkout your repo1_to_import if you don't have it already 
git clone url:repo1_to_import repo1_to_import
cd repo1_to_import

# now. pull all of repo_dest
git pull url:repo_dest
ls 
git status # shows Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by xx commits.
# now push to repo_dest
git push --set-upstream url:repo_dest master

# repeat for other repositories you want to import
```

Rename or move files and dirs into desired position in original repo before you do the import. e.g.

```
cd repo1_to_import
mkdir topDir
git add topDir
git mv this that and the other topDir/
git commit -m"move things into topDir in preparation for exporting into new repo"
# now do the pull and push to import
```

The method described at the following link inspired this answer. I liked it as it seemed more simple. BUT Beware! There be dragons! https://help.github.com/articles/importing-an-external-git-repository `git push --mirror url:repo_dest` pushes your local repo history and state to remote (url:repo_dest). BUT it deletes the old history and state of the remote. Fun ensues! :-E

Answer (score 2):

Here is the script that will work right off the bat.

```sh
#!/bin/bash -xe
# script name: merge-repo.sh
# To merge repositories into the current.
# To see the log of the new repo use 'git log --follow -- unprefixed-filename'
# So if the file is repo/test.cpp use 'git log --follow -- test.cpp'
# I'm not sure how this will work when two files have the same name.
#
# `git branch -a` will show newly created branches.
# You can delete them if you want.
merge_another() {
    repo="$1" # url of the remote repo
    rn="$2"   # new name of the repo, you can keep the same name as well.
    git remote add ${rn} ${repo}
    git fetch ${rn}
    git merge -s ours --no-commit --allow-unrelated-histories ${rn}/master
    git read-tree --prefix=${rn}/ -u ${rn}/master
    git commit -m "Imported ${rn} as a subtree."
    git pull -s subtree ${rn} master
}

merge_another $1 $2
```

To run the script. Go to the repo where you want the other repo to be merged, and run the script.

```sh
cd base-repo
./merge-repo.sh git@github.com:username/repo-to-be-merged.git repo-to-be-merged-new-name
```

Now push the changes on the master branch to remote/origin. This step may not be required depending on what you are trying to do.

```sh
git push origin master
```

Comment: It worked well, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to import only some files from the other repository (XXX) in my case. The subtree was too complicated for me and the other solutions didn't work. This is what I did:

```
ALL_COMMITS=$(git log --reverse --pretty=format:%H -- ZZZ | tr '\n' ' ')
```

This gives you a space-separated list of all the commits that affect the files I wanted to import (ZZZ) in reverse order (you might have to add --follow to capture renames as well). I then went into the target repository (YYY), added the other repository (XXX) as remote, did a fetch from it and finally:

```
git cherry-pick $ALL_COMMITS
```

which adds all the commits to your branch, you'll thus have all the files with their history and can do whatever you want with them as if they've always been in this repository.

Answer (score 1):

See **Basic example** in [this article](http://blog.caplin.com/2013/09/18/merging-two-git-repositories/) and consider such mapping on repositories:

- `A` <-> `YYY`,
- `B` <-> `XXX`

After all activity described in this chapter (after merging), remove branch `B-master`:

```
$ git branch -d B-master
```

Then, push changes.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a situation where I was looking for `-s theirs` but of course, this strategy doesn't exist.  My history was that I had forked a project on GitHub, and now for some reason, my local `master` could not be merged with `upstream/master` although I had made no local changes to this branch. (Really don't know what happened there -- I guess upstream had done some dirty pushes behind the scenes, maybe?)

What I ended up doing was

```
# as per https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
....
# Lots of conflicts, ended up just abandonging this approach
git reset --hard   # Ditch failed merge
git checkout upstream/master
# Now in detached state
git branch -d master # !
git checkout -b master   # create new master from upstream/master
```

So now my `master` is again in sync with `upstream/master` (and you could repeat the above for any other branch you also want to sync similarly).

Comment: A `git reset --hard upstream/master` on your local `master` branch would do the job. This way you don’t lose local branch conflg – things like the default upstream.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest another solution (alternative to [git-submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)) for your problem - [gil (git links) tool](https://github.com/chronoxor/gil)

It allows to describe and manage complex git repositories dependencies.

Also it provides a solution to the [git recursive submodules dependency problem](https://github.com/chronoxor/gil#recursive-submodules-problem).

Consider you have the following project dependencies:
[sample git repository dependency graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUM5M.png)

Then you can define `.gitlinks` file with repositories relation description:

```
# Projects
CppBenchmark CppBenchmark https://github.com/chronoxor/CppBenchmark.git master
CppCommon CppCommon https://github.com/chronoxor/CppCommon.git master
CppLogging CppLogging https://github.com/chronoxor/CppLogging.git master

# Modules
Catch2 modules/Catch2 https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2.git master
cpp-optparse modules/cpp-optparse https://github.com/weisslj/cpp-optparse.git master
fmt modules/fmt https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git master
HdrHistogram modules/HdrHistogram https://github.com/HdrHistogram/HdrHistogram_c.git master
zlib modules/zlib https://github.com/madler/zlib.git master

# Scripts
build scripts/build https://github.com/chronoxor/CppBuildScripts.git master
cmake scripts/cmake https://github.com/chronoxor/CppCMakeScripts.git master
```

Each line describe git link in the following format:

1. Unique name of the repository
2. Relative path of the repository (started from the path of .gitlinks file)
3. Git repository which will be used in git clone command
   Repository branch to checkout
4. Empty line or line started with # are not parsed (treated as comment).

Finally you have to update your root sample repository:

```
# Clone and link all git links dependencies from .gitlinks file
gil clone
gil link

# The same result with a single command
gil update
```

As the result you'll clone all required projects and link them to each other in a proper way.

If you want to commit all changes in some repository with all changes in child linked repositories you can do it with a single command:

```
gil commit -a -m "Some big update"
```

Pull, push commands works in a similar way:

```
gil pull
gil push
```

Gil (git links) tool supports the following commands:

```
usage: gil command arguments
Supported commands:
    help - show this help
    context - command will show the current git link context of the current directory
    clone - clone all repositories that are missed in the current context
    link - link all repositories that are missed in the current context
    update - clone and link in a single operation
    pull - pull all repositories in the current directory
    push - push all repositories in the current directory
    commit - commit all repositories in the current directory
```

More about [git recursive submodules dependency problem](https://github.com/chronoxor/gil#recursive-submodules-problem).

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough rep to add a comment to x-yuri's answer, but it works beautifully and preserves history.
I was working with two working local repo's and received this error:

> Aborting: Refusing to destructively overwrite repo history since
> this does not look like a fresh clone.
> (expected freshly packed repo)
> Please operate on a fresh clone instead.  If you want to proceed anyway, use --force.

Rather than worry about the implications of the `--force` flag, I cloned the repo locally first with:

```
cd tempDir
git clone <location of repo to be merged> --no-local
```

and used this freshly cloned copy for the series of commands that x-yuri laid out.
Lastly, in: `git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter a`, `a` is the name you are giving to the root folder for the repo that you will be importing.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know of an easy way to do that.  You COULD do this:

1. Use git filter-branch to add a ZZZ super-directory on the XXX repository
2. Push the new branch to the YYY repository
3. Merge the pushed branch with YYY's trunk.

I can edit with details if that sounds appealing.

Answer (score -3):

I think you can do this using 'git mv' and 'git pull'.

I'm a fair git noob - so be careful with your main repository - but I just tried this in a temp dir and it seems to work.

First - rename the structure of XXX to match how you want it to look when it's within YYY:

```
cd XXX
mkdir tmp
git mv ZZZ tmp/ZZZ
git mv tmp ZZZ
```

Now XXX looks like this:

```
XXX
 |- ZZZ
     |- ZZZ
```

Now use 'git pull' to fetch the changes across:

```
cd ../YYY
git pull ../XXX
```

Now YYY looks like this:

```
YYY
 |- ZZZ
     |- ZZZ
 |- (other folders that already were in YYY)
```