# How to un-submodule a Git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

What are the best practices for un-submoduling a Git submodule, bringing all the code back into the core repository?

Comment: Note: with git1.8.3, you can now try a **`git submodule deinit`**, see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16162228/6309)

Comment: I may misunderstand, but git submodule deinit seems to remove the code.

Comment: Since git 1.8.5 (November 2013), a simple `git submodule deinit asubmodule ; git rm asubmodule` is enough, as illustrated in [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16162228/6309)

Comment: consider using git [subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33579069/1342413)

Answer (score 664):

If all you want is to put your submodule code into the main repository, you just need to remove the submodule and re-add the files into the main repo:

```bash
git rm --cached submodule_path # delete reference to submodule HEAD (no trailing slash)
git rm .gitmodules             # if you have more than one submodules,
                                # you need to edit this file instead of deleting!
rm -rf submodule_path/.git     # make sure you have backup!!
git add submodule_path         # will add files instead of commit reference
git commit -m "remove submodule"
```

If you also want to preserve the history of the submodule, you can do a small trick: “merge” the submodule into the main repository, so that the result will be the same as it was before, except that the submodule files are now in the main repository.

In the main module you will need to do the following:

```bash
# Fetch the submodule commits into the main repository
git remote add submodule_origin git://url/to/submodule/origin
git fetch submodule_origin

# Start a fake merge (won't change any files, won't commit anything)
git merge -s ours --no-commit submodule_origin/master

# Do the same as in the first solution
git rm --cached submodule_path # delete reference to submodule HEAD
git rm .gitmodules             # if you have more than one submodules,
                                # you need to edit this file instead of deleting!
rm -rf submodule_path/.git     # make sure you have backup!!
git add submodule_path         # will add files instead of commit reference

# Commit and cleanup
git commit -m "removed submodule"
git remote rm submodule_origin
```

The resulting repository will look a bit weird: there will be more than one initial commit. But it won’t cause any problems for Git.

A big advantage of this second solution is that you can still run `git blame` or `git log` on the files which were originally in submodules. In fact, what happens here is just a renaming of many files inside one repository, and Git should automatically detect this. If you still have problems with `git log`, try some options (e.g., `--follow`, `-M`, `-C`) which do better rename and copy detection.

Comment: I think I need to do your second method (history preserving) on some git repos I have. Could you please explain which part of the above commands causes the files from the submodule to end up in the subdirectory? Is it that you when you do the merge git brings in the file in the top level directory (with its history) but when you do the git add submodule_path it implicity does a git mv for every file?

Comment: Basically, yes. The trick is that git does not store rename operations: instead, it detects them by looking at the parent commits. If there is a file content that was present in the previous commit, but with a different filename, it is considered a rename (or copy). In the steps above, `git merge` ensures that there will be a "previous commit" for every file (at one of the two "sides" of the merge).

Comment: And yes, since the files were in the root directory in the "submodule side" of the history, git will see a merge AND a bunch of renames in the commit.

Comment: Thanks gyim, I started a project where I thought it made sense to split things into a couple of repositories and link them back together with submodules. But now it seems over engineered and I want to combine them back together without losing my history.

Comment: After following the instructions exactly, his does not work for me anymore in git 1.8.
Git does not detect the files as moved, but says they are new!
Any idea why?

Comment: a git alias for this would be of great help!

Comment: @theduke I also had this problem. It can be fixed by, before following these steps, moving all of the files from your submodules repository into a directory structure with *the same path* as the repository that you are about to merge into: ie. if your submodule in the main repository is in foo/, in the submodule, perform `mkdir foo && git mv !(foo) foo && git commit`.

Comment: On Git 1.9.3 here, and sadly I can't get these instructions to work properly. I am just seeing one git log entry where in one commit i added every single file from the submodule. I think maybe it breaks somewhere around the `git merge` command. For me it just gave an immediate "merge failed" message, and the two `git rm` commands after it did not succeed either.

Comment: This answer makes a lot more sense to me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1684694/340947

Comment: About detecting renames: it is normal that the merged files appear as newly added. Git does not have a notion of moving/renaming, `git mv` is exactly the same as deleting a file and adding it under a new name. If you use `git log --follow <filename>`, it will detect renames and show the history properly.

Comment: By the way, this solution results in almost the same thing as http://stackoverflow.com/a/1684694/340947 (referenced by @StevenLu). The main differences are: 1. we need to "un-submodule" here as well in addition to pulling the files from the other repo; 2. we do the merging, file renaming and "un-submoduling" in a single commit (this is why we use `git merge --no-commit`)

Comment: While this does preserve history, I can't checkout or pull the SHA from a SHA with the submodule instead of the folder.  git complains that `The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge` and lists all files in my submodule.   `git reset --hard` does seem to work, but normal checkouts and pulls do not work.  Is this expected?

Comment: Note that the non-history preserving approach (at the top) in recent version of git does not remove .git/modules/packages/submodule_name -- this is where the submodule's git repository is stored (not in submodule_path/.git as it used to be in earlier versions of git). I just removed this folder manually. (This folder will be removed by the "git rm" step in the "Since git 1.8.5" answer.)

Comment: Needed to add `--allow-unrelated-histories` to force the merge at the fake merge as I was getting `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`, more here: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.9.0.txt#L58-L68

Comment: I think `git submodule deinit` would be better than `git rm .gitmodules` since you may have other submodules.

Comment: it does not preserve history, if I type after `git log subdirectory_where_submodule" it does not show all history.

Comment: Same for me. This does not seem to be preserving the history

Comment: What if there are other submodules inside the submodule being removed?

Comment: ...and you still want to preserve those children as submodules.

Comment: `git log --name-status` shows the paths of files in the preserved-, merged history remaining relative to their former submodule root dir. Would it be possible to rewrite that history making the paths reflect their files' new root?

Answer (score 104):

I've created a script that will translate a submodule to a simple directory, while retaining all file history.  It doesn't suffer from the `git log --follow <file>` issues that the other solutions suffer from.  It's also a very easy one-line invocation that does all of the work for you.  G'luck.

It builds on the excellent work by Lucas Jenß, described in his blog post "[Integrating a submodule into the parent repository](https://x3ro.de/2013/09/01/Integrating-a-submodule-into-the-parent-repository.html)", but automates the entire process and cleans up a few other corner cases.

The latest code will be maintained with bugfixes on github at https://github.com/jeremysears/scripts/blob/master/bin/git-submodule-rewrite, but for the sake of proper stackoverflow answer protocol, I've included the solution in its entirety below.

Usage:

```
$ git-submodule-rewrite <submodule-name>
```

**git-submodule-rewrite:**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This script builds on the excellent work by Lucas Jenß, described in his blog
# post "Integrating a submodule into the parent repository", but automates the
# entire process and cleans up a few other corner cases.
# https://x3ro.de/2013/09/01/Integrating-a-submodule-into-the-parent-repository.html

function usage() {
  echo "Merge a submodule into a repo, retaining file history."
  echo "Usage: $0 <submodule-name>"
  echo ""
  echo "options:"
  echo "  -h, --help                Print this message"
  echo "  -v, --verbose             Display verbose output"
}

function abort {
    echo "$(tput setaf 1)$1$(tput sgr0)"
    exit 1
}

function request_confirmation {
    read -p "$(tput setaf 4)$1 (y/n) $(tput sgr0)"
    [ "$REPLY" == "y" ] || abort "Aborted!"
}

function warn() {
  cat << EOF
    This script will convert your "${sub}" git submodule into
    a simple subdirectory in the parent repository while retaining all
    contents and file history.

    The script will:
      * delete the ${sub} submodule configuration from .gitmodules and
        .git/config and commit it.
      * rewrite the entire history of the ${sub} submodule so that all
        paths are prefixed by ${path}.
        This ensures that git log will correctly follow the original file
        history.
      * merge the submodule into its parent repository and commit it.

    NOTE: This script might completely garble your repository, so PLEASE apply
    this only to a fresh clone of the repository where it does not matter if
    the repo is destroyed.  It would be wise to keep a backup clone of your
    repository, so that you can reconstitute it if need be.  You have been
    warned.  Use at your own risk.

EOF

  request_confirmation "Do you want to proceed?"
}

function git_version_lte() {
  OP_VERSION=$(printf "%03d%03d%03d%03d" $(echo "$1" | tr '.' '\n' | head -n 4))
  GIT_VERSION=$(git version)
  GIT_VERSION=$(printf "%03d%03d%03d%03d" $(echo "${GIT_VERSION#git version}" | tr '.' '\n' | head -n 4))
  echo -e "${GIT_VERSION}\n${OP_VERSION}" | sort | head -n1
  [ ${OP_VERSION} -le ${GIT_VERSION} ]
}

function main() {

  warn

  if [ "${verbose}" == "true" ]; then
    set -x
  fi

  # Remove submodule and commit
  git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section "submodule.${sub}"
  if git config -f .git/config --get "submodule.${sub}.url"; then
    git config -f .git/config --remove-section "submodule.${sub}"
  fi
  rm -rf "${path}"
  git add -A .
  git commit -m "Remove submodule ${sub}"
  rm -rf ".git/modules/${sub}"

  # Rewrite submodule history
  local tmpdir="$(mktemp -d -t submodule-rewrite-XXXXXX)"
  git clone "${url}" "${tmpdir}"
  pushd "${tmpdir}"
  local tab="$(printf '\t')"
  local filter="git ls-files -s | sed \"s/${tab}/${tab}${path}\//\" | GIT_INDEX_FILE=\${GIT_INDEX_FILE}.new git update-index --index-info && mv \${GIT_INDEX_FILE}.new \${GIT_INDEX_FILE}"
  git filter-branch --index-filter "${filter}" HEAD
  popd

  # Merge in rewritten submodule history
  git remote add "${sub}" "${tmpdir}"
  git fetch "${sub}"

  if git_version_lte 2.8.4
  then
    # Previous to git 2.9.0 the parameter would yield an error
    ALLOW_UNRELATED_HISTORIES=""
  else
    # From git 2.9.0 this parameter is required
    ALLOW_UNRELATED_HISTORIES="--allow-unrelated-histories"
  fi

  git merge -s ours --no-commit ${ALLOW_UNRELATED_HISTORIES} "${sub}/master"
  rm -rf tmpdir

  # Add submodule content
  git clone "${url}" "${path}"
  rm -rf "${path}/.git"
  git add "${path}"
  git commit -m "Merge submodule contents for ${sub}"
  git config -f .git/config --remove-section "remote.${sub}"

  set +x
  echo "$(tput setaf 2)Submodule merge complete. Push changes after review.$(tput sgr0)"
}

set -euo pipefail

declare verbose=false
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
        (-h|--help)
            usage
            exit 0
            ;;
        (-v|--verbose)
            verbose=true
            ;;
        (*)
            break
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

declare sub="${1:-}"

if [ -z "${sub}" ]; then
  >&2 echo "Error: No submodule specified"
  usage
  exit 1
fi

shift

if [ -n "${1:-}" ]; then
  >&2 echo "Error: Unknown option: ${1:-}"
  usage
  exit 1
fi

if ! [ -d ".git" ]; then
  >&2 echo "Error: No git repository found.  Must be run from the root of a git repository"
  usage
  exit 1
fi

declare path="$(git config -f .gitmodules --get "submodule.${sub}.path")"
declare url="$(git config -f .gitmodules --get "submodule.${sub}.url")"

if [ -z "${path}" ]; then
  >&2 echo "Error: Submodule not found: ${sub}"
  usage
  exit 1
fi

if ! [ -d "${path}" ]; then
  >&2 echo "Error: Submodule path not found: ${path}"
  usage
  exit 1
fi

main
```

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 16.04. I sent [a pull request](https://github.com/jeremysears/scripts/pull/2) to the Github repo.

Comment: Good catch, @qznc.  This was tested on OSX.  I'll happily merge that when it passes on both platforms.

Comment: @qznc Ubuntu 16.04 support merged and answer updated.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I got it to work perfectly in Windows 10 by grabbing [your latest script from GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jeremysears/scripts/master/bin/git-submodule-rewrite) and running it under [WSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/commandline/wsl/install_guide).

Comment: Still works on macOS 10.12.6 with git version 2.10.1 (Apple Git-78), to check the name of the submodule, just type `cat .gitmodules`.

Comment: This worked great for me but not on WSL - got an error suggesting a mix of forward- and back-slashes going into the reconstructed paths? So ran it on macOS instead and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Failed on Cygwin with: fatal: Unable to create '/tmp/submodule-rewrite-9J3x5U/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory It worked however on CentOS 7 like a charm. Good job !!!!

Comment: Thanks for the awesome solution! I wish it included an explanation as to what'll happen once this is merged into master and someone pulls it. Will the submodule be properly replaced by git?

Comment: Do all work without errors in Git Bash 2.20.1.1 on Windows 10 with latest version from github: `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jeremysears/scripts/master/bin/git-submodule-rewrite > git-submodule-rewrite.sh` and `./git-submodule-rewrite.sh <submodule-name>`

Comment: is it possible to do this with only one commit? right now there is one for removing submodule and the other for creating the folder. By the way the second commit is a merge commit and I could not rebase them.

Comment: In my experience with submodules I had a hard time doing anything related to removing an existing version of a submodule unless I did a full proper removal (even just renaming a submodule, actually)

Comment: works great on mac os 10.14 mojave+latest git (2.24.1)

Comment: @jsears hi, quick question: do I have to run this script from master branch?

Comment: I run the script from develop on my windows pc but it failed "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-filter-branch: line 468: ../message: Permission denied"

Comment: Do you know the reason why I get the following error:

´
Rewrite d791f0933e0f4a58ff8c2c06d17f69455a35a09e (2/221) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    mv: cannot stat '/tmp/submodule-rewrite-bDhx95/.git-rewrite/t/../index.new': No such file or directory
index filter failed: git ls-files -s | sed "s/ / mysubmodule\//" | GIT_INDEX_FILE=${GIT_INDEX_FILE}.new git update-index --index-info && mv ${GIT_INDEX_FILE}.new ${GIT_INDEX_FILE}
´

Comment: After using the updated script from the github to ignore those above: I get a bunch following:

! [rejected]        1.0.0          -> 1.0.0  (would clobber existing tag)
 ! [rejected]        1.0.0-rc1      -> 1.0.0-rc1  (would clobber existing tag)
 ! [rejected]        1.0.0-rc2      -> 1.0.0-rc2  (would clobber existing tag)
 ! [rejected]        1.0.0-rc3      -> 1.0.0-rc3  (would clobber existing tag)
 ! [rejected]        1.0.1          -> 1.0.1  (would clobber existing tag)
 ! [rejected]        1.0.2          -> 1.0.2  (would clobber existing tag)

Answer (score 87):

Since [git 1.8.5 (Nov 2013](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95c16418f0375e2fc325f32c3d7578fba9cfd7ef)) (**without keeping the history of the submodule**):

```
mv yoursubmodule yoursubmodule_tmp
git submodule deinit yourSubmodule
git rm yourSubmodule
mv yoursubmodule_tmp yoursubmodule
git add yoursubmodule
```

That will:

- unregister and **unload** (ie **delete the content of**) the submodule (`deinit`, hence the `mv` *first*),
- clean up the `.gitmodules` for you (`rm`),
- and remove the [special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) representing that submodule SHA1 in the index of the parent repo (`rm`).

Once the removal of the submodule is complete (`deinit` and `git rm`), you can rename the folder back to its original name and add it to the git repo as a regular folder.

Note: if the submodule was created by an old Git (< 1.8), you might need to remove the nested `.git` folder within the submodule itself, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759587/un-submodule-a-git-submodule/16162228#comment76658271_16162228) by [Simon East](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195835/simon-east)

---

If you need to keep the history of the submodule, see [jsears](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240482/jsears)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43554035/6309), which uses `git filter-branch`.

Comment: This actually does delete it from the working tree in 1.8.4 (my entire submodule dir was cleared).

Comment: @ChrisDown you mean, the `deinit` alone cleaned the working tree from your submodule?

Comment: Yeah, it removes all the content in the submodule directory.

Comment: I can confirm it does clear the submodule in the working tree. Any way to keep it?

Comment: @CharlesB it (`git submodule deinit`) does clear it, but it doesn't remove the special entry from the index, does it?

Comment: @VonC: no, and it still has to exist as an index entry since you deinit without remove? It still shows an entry in `git ls-tree HEAD path/to/sub`

Comment: @CharlesB just checkin. So the problem remains: how to do a `git submodule deinit` *without* having the working tree of that submodule disappear, right,.

Comment: `git config --remove-section submodule.name`, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20097046/11343?

Comment: @CharlesB yes, that would mimic what git submodule deinit does (minus maybe the rm -Rf `.git/modules/xxx`), without the all "removing the working tree" part.

Comment: @VonC Does this maintain the history of all of the commits made to the submodule or does it just make a single commit of the files as-is with no history?

Comment: @cottonBallPaws it does maintain the history of the files within the submodule. This only affects the parent repo.

Comment: @VonC So if the submodule has 5 commits to it, and I then use this method to move its files into the parent repo as the parent repo's files instead of as a submodule, the 5 commits history will be preserved for the files after they are in the parent repo?  Thanks!

Comment: ```That means to really unsubmodule a submodule, you will do (git 1.8.5 or 1.9, Q4 2013) (...)``` - But that is wrong. ```git submodule deinit SubModule``` does remove the files from the working tree. If you do ```git rm --cached SubModule``` your files are already gone from the working tree.

Comment: @VonC Well the goal is to un-submodule a submodule. This means to add the submodule files to the parent repository without the reference to a submodule. I haven't found an easy solution using ```git submodule deinit SubModule```. When using this command the files are gone from disk. Or do I get something wrong?

Comment: @and-dev I haven't tested it recently, but at the time, gone from the disk didn't mean gone from the index.

Comment: @VonC And which command should restore it from the index? ```git rm --cached yourSubmodule``` does only delete the last traces of yourSubModule being a submodule right? So what would be the complete setup to un-submodule a submodule while keeping the files on disk? (that need to be added as normal tracked files to the parent project)

Comment: @and-dev simply rename the submodule folder before doing  the `git submodule deinit yourSubmodule && git rm --cached yourSubmodule`. Then rename it back.

Comment: This answer is terrifying.  It doesn't clearly explain which process to use, or what to avoid.

Comment: @TimOgilvy I have simplified the answer.

Comment: Given that the original question asks how to keep the files in the working tree, but convert the sub-module to integrated code, it's now apparent that this is both 

 a) an incomplete answer, and  

 b) dangerous. 

At least please add a warning, that this will remove the subodule files?

Comment: @TimOgilvy I have clarified the steps to preserve the content of the submodule.

Comment: Sure.  Why is everyone so obsessed with the word **unload**?  It's somewhat jargony.  What it does, in plain terms, is delete the submodule. I like the word **delete** - it's unambiguous, and given that SO is for people trying to learn stuff, I reckon being unambiguous is a nifty concept.

Comment: @TimOgilvy OK. I have added the word **delete**.

Comment: Am i missing something? This leaves the submodule with a .git folder in it and adding it back into the repo just creates a subproject. Not sure how this is getting upvoted as it's not great advice and doesn't explain to people at all what you are doing (even if it was the right way to do this) just that they should bash these commands into the terminal.

Comment: @mschuett no, you are not missing anything: a submodule does not have a .git in it in the first place. If that was the case for you, it was a nested repo, not a submodule. That explains why this answer above would not apply in your case. For the difference between the two, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34410102/6309.

Comment: Not sure I follow. I have this listed in my .gitsubmoules file `
[submodule "phacility/phabricator"]
  path = phacility/phabricator
  url = https://github.com/phacility/phabricator.git
` and when I run `git submodule init && git submodule update` to pull them in they all contain a .git folder. Sorry for formatting.

Comment: @mschuett what version of git are you using?

Comment: `git version 1.9.1` which is the current stock version shipped on ubuntu.

Comment: @mschuett that would explain why, submodules have changed *a lot* since that old version. Try upgrading git first: http://askubuntu.com/a/579591/5470

Comment: Sounds good. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something completely stupid. Although using stock ubuntu packages is in that realm.

Comment: I think this is missing a step. The resulting submodule folder still has a `.git` file there which prevents it from being committed to the parent repo.

Comment: @SimonEast What Git version are you using?

Comment: @VonC I'm currently on 2.9.0.windows.1, however the submodules may have been created several years ago on a much earlier version of git, I'm not sure. I think the steps seem to work as long as I remove that file before doing the final add + commit.

Comment: @SimonEast OK that would make sense. I will edit the steps shortly

Comment: It does not preserve history.

Comment: @user1244932 Yes, that is on purpose. For preserving the history, see the answer above.

Comment: Looks like stackoverflow reoder content based on user, because of no answer above yours. May be you mean answer with >300 votes? It is also wrong, it need at least call to `git filter-branch` to get right answer. But anyway, it is version control system, and answer that throw away history is very bad, it should at least mention damage of history with bold somehwere at the top.

Comment: @user1244932 Good point. I have added the warning (in bold), and added a link to the answer which uses `git filter-branch` and preserves the history.

Comment: I had to commit after removing, remove `.git`, and commit again after adding - `mv`, `deinit`, `git rm -r`, **`commit`**, **`rm -rf <submod>_tmp/.git`**, `mv`, `add`, **`commit`**.

Comment: @cxw with which version of Git?

Comment: Git 2.17.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 x64 (shell bash 4.4.20(1), in case that matters).

Comment: @cxw OK. I would be curious to know if this is necessary with Git 2.23.

Answer (score 45):

1. `git rm --cached the_submodule_path`
2. remove the submodule section from the `.gitmodules` file, or if it's the only submodule, remove the file.
3. do a commit "removed submodule xyz"
4. `git add the_submodule_path`
5. another commit "added codebase of xyz"

I didn't find any easier way yet. You can compress 3-5 into one step via `git commit -a` - matter of taste.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.gitmodules` instead of `.submodules`?

Comment: It should be ```.gitmodules``` not ```.submodules```

Comment: I had to remove the `.git` directory of the submodule before `git add` would work on the submodule folder

Comment: Seconding Carson Evans, You definitely have to remove the .git file at the root of the submodule. This should be step 2.5.

Answer (score 19):

Lots of answers here but all of them seem to be overly complex and likely do not do what you want. I am sure most people want to keep their history.

For this example the main repo will be `git@site.com:main/main.git` and the submodule repo will be `git@site.com:main/child.git`. This assumes that the submodule is located in the root directory of the parent repo. Adjust the instructions as needed.

Start by cloning the parent repo and removing the old submodule.

```
git clone git@site.com:main/main.git
git submodule deinit child
git rm child
git add --all
git commit -m "remove child submodule"
```

Now we will add the child repos upstream to the main repo.

```
git remote add upstream git@site.com:main/child.git
git fetch upstream
git checkout -b merge-prep upstream/master
```

The next step assumes that you want to move the files on the merge-prep branch into the same location as the submodule was above although you can easily change the location by changing the file path.

```
mkdir child
```

move all folders and files except the .git folder into the child folder.

```
git add --all
git commit -m "merge prep"
```

Now you can simply merge your files back into the master branch.

```
git checkout master
git merge merge-prep # --allow-unrelated-histories merge-prep flag may be required
```

Look around and make sure everything looks good before running `git push`

The one thing you have to remember now is that git log does not by default follow moved files however by running `git log --follow filename` you can see the full history of your files.

Comment: I got all the way to the final `git merge merge-prep` and received the error `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`.  Workaround is this: `git merge  --allow-unrelated-histories merge-prep`.

Comment: @humblehacker thanks i added a little comment in case others run into this as well.

Comment: The best answer to keep history of submodule. Thank you @mschuett

Comment: In the example here, is there any way to fetch the upstream's files into the `child` directory, so you don't have to move them later? I have the same file names in a submodule and the main repo... so I just get a merge conflict since it's trying to merge the two files together.

Comment: Possibly but I don't know it offhand. I would personally just make a commit moving the files in the repo you are trying to move in so they reside in the directory you want before pulling them in.

Comment: hi. if I do this operation on the master branch I guess all the branches in the repo will reflect the new structire, correct?

Comment: @gianpaolo if you rebase/merge master into them then yes.

Answer (score 12):

It happened to us that we created 2 repositories for 2 projects that were so coupled that didn't make any sense to have them separated, so we merged them.

I'll show how to merge the master branches in each first and then I will explain how you can extend this to every branches you got, hope it helps you.

If you got the submodule working, and you want to convert it to a directory in place you can do:

```
git clone project_uri project_name
```

Here we do a clean clone to work. For this process you don't need to initialize or update the submodules, so just skip it.

```
cd project_name
vim .gitmodules
```

Edit `.gitmodules` with your favorite editor (or Vim) to remove the submodule you plan to replace. The lines you need to remove should look something like this:

```
[submodule "lib/asi-http-request"]
    path = lib/asi-http-request
    url = https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request.git
```

After saving the file,

```
git rm --cached directory_of_submodule
git commit -am "Removed submodule_name as submodule"
rm -rf directory_of_submodule
```

Here we remove the submodule relation completely so we can create bring the other repo to the project in-place.

```
git remote add -f submodule_origin submodule_uri
git fetch submodel_origin/master
```

Here we fetch the submodule repository to merge.

```
git merge -s ours --no-commit submodule_origin/master
```

Here we start a merge operation of the 2 repositories, but stop before commit.

```
git read-tree --prefix=directory_of_submodule/ -u submodule_origin/master
```

Here we send the content of master in the submodule to the directory where it was before prefixing a directory name

```
git commit -am "submodule_name is now part of main project"
```

Here we complete the procedure doing a commit of the changes in the merge.

After finishing this you can push, and start again with any other branch to merge, just checkout the branch in you repository that will receive the changes and change the branch you bringing in the merge and read-tree operations.

Comment: this doesn't seemed to have preserved history of the submodule files, I just see a single commit in the git log for the files added under `directory_of_submodule`

Comment: @Anentropic Sorry for the delay to reply. I just did the full procedure again (with a small fix). The procedure keeps the whole history, but it has a merge point, maybe that is why you don't find it.
If you want to see the submodule history just do a "git log", lookup for the merge commit (in the example is the one with message "submodule_name is now part of main project").
It will have 2 parent commits (Merge: sdasda asdasd), git log the second commit and you got all your submodule/master history there.

Comment: my memory is hazy now but I think I was able to get the history of the merged submodule files by doing `git log original_path_of_file_in_submodule` i.e. the path registered in the git repo for the file (which doesn't any longer exist on the filesystem) even though the submodule file now lives at `submodule_path/new_path_of_file`

Comment: This doesn't preserve the history very well, and also the paths are wrong.  I feel that something like a tree-filter is needed but I'm out of my depth...  trying what I've found here:  http://x3ro.de/2013/09/01/Integrating-a-submodule-into-the-parent-repository.html

Comment: This answer is obsolete, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162228/11343 (VonC answer) does the same but better

Comment: `git log --follow $file_from_read_tree` or with any other option will not work after this. I ended up doing the same as this with the exception of having a local branch of the submodule, renaming all of its files under the new "subtree path", doing the "ours" merge and then reading the tree with empty prefix and merging. This allows the `git log --follow` to find the commits. You need to remove/add any nested submodules temporarily. Quite the hassle!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a slightly improved version (IMHO) of @gyim's answer.  He is doing a bunch of dangerous changes in the main working copy, where I think it's much easier to operate on separate clones and then merge them together at the end.

In a separate directory (to make mistakes easier to clean up and try again) check out both the top repo and the subrepo.

```
git clone ../main_repo main.tmp
git clone ../main_repo/sub_repo sub.tmp
```

First edit the subrepo to move all files into the desired subdirectory

```
cd sub.tmp
mkdir sub_repo_path
git mv `ls | grep -v sub_repo_path` sub_repo_path/
git commit -m "Moved entire subrepo into sub_repo_path"
```

Make a note of the HEAD

```
SUBREPO_HEAD=`git reflog | awk '{ print $1; exit; }'`
```

Now remove the subrepo from the main repo

```
cd ../main.tmp
rmdir sub_repo_path
vi .gitmodules  # remove config for submodule
git add -A
git commit -m "Removed submodule sub_repo_path in preparation for merge"
```

And finally, just merge them

```
git fetch ../sub.tmp
# remove --allow-unrelated-histories if using git older than 2.9.0
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories $SUBREPO_HEAD
```

And done!  Safely and without any magic.

Comment: ... which answer is that? Might want to reference the username as well as the top answer can change over time.

Comment: @Contango answer updated.  but the top answer is still the top answer by a 400 point lead ;-)

Comment: Does this work if the subrepo already contains a directory named `subrepo` with stuff in it?

Comment: In the last step I get following error:
`git merge $SUBREPO_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`
Should I use
`git merge $SUBREPO_HEAD --allow-unrelated-histories`
in this case? Or should it work without and I made a mistake?

Comment: @Ti-m Yes, this is exactly the case of merging two histories that do not share any commits.  The guard against unrelated histories seems to be new in git since I first wrote this; I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 6):

The best answer to this I have found is here:

http://x3ro.de/2013/09/01/Integrating-a-submodule-into-the-parent-repository.html

This article explains the procedure very well.

Answer (score 3):

For when

```
git rm [-r] --cached submodule_path
```

returns

```
fatal: pathspec 'emr/normalizers/' did not match any files
```

---

Context: I did `rm -r .git*` in my submodule folders before realizing that they needed to be de-submoduled in the main project to which I had just added them. I got the above error when de-submoduling some, but not all of them. Anyway, I fixed them by running, (after, of course, the `rm -r .git*`)

```
mv submodule_path submodule_path.temp
git add -A .
git commit -m "De-submodulization phase 1/2"
mv submodule_path.temp submodule_path
git add -A .
git commit -m "De-submodulization phase 2/2"
```

Note that this doesn't preserve history.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162228/157971), I have created a simple bash script that does this. The `add` at the end has to use wildcards otherwise it will undo the previous `rm` for the submodule itself. It's important to add the *contents* of the submodule directory, and not to name the directory itself in the `add` command.

In a file called `git-integrate-submodule`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mv "$1" "${1}_"
git submodule deinit "$1"
git rm "$1"
mv "${1}_" "$1"
git add "$1/**"
```

Answer (score 2):

In main repo

- git rm --cached [submodules_repo]
- git commit -m "Submodules removed."
- git push origin [master]

In submodules repo

- rm -rf .git

Again main repo

- git add [submodules_repo]
- git add .
- git commit -m "Submodules repo added into main."
- git push origin [master]

Comment: There are already several answers here, and most of them include lots of explanation. Does this answer introduce new information? Please read [answer].

Comment: This answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found it more convenient to (also?) fetch local commit data from the submodule, because otherwise I would loose them. (Could not push them as I have not access to that remote). So I added submodule/.git as remote_origin2, fetched it commits and merged from that branch. 
Not sure if I still need the submodule remote as origin, since I am not familiar enough with git yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found best & simplest.

In submodule repo, from HEAD you want to merge into main repo:

- `git checkout -b "mergeMe"`
- `mkdir "foo/bar/myLib/"` (identical path as where you want the files on main repo)
- `git mv * "foo/bar/myLib/"` (move all into path)
- `git commit -m "ready to merge into main"`

Back in main repo after removing the submodule and clearing the path "foo/bar/myLib":

- `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories SubmoduleOriginRemote/mergeMe`

boom done

histories preserved

no worries

---

Note this nearly identical to some other answers. But this assumes you own submodule repo. Also this makes it easy to get future upstream changes for submodule.