# Merge git submodule into main repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

Ok, we have a repository with 3 submodules. Now we want to merge this submodules back into main repository, keeping all history (well, using submodules turned out to be more headache than being usefull). How do we proceed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [un-submodule a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759587/un-submodule-a-git-submodule)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you have the following filesystem (and let's assume you only have one submodule, to simply the answer)

```bash
myRepoRoot
├── myMainFiles/
└── submodule/
```

You just need to do:

```bash
# Preparing the filesystems
cd submodule
# "submodule" is basically the path where you need your submodule code to be in the new repository,
# e.g. app/code/x/y (<-- in this case you need to create multiple folders ofc, not just one like seen here)
mkdir submodule
git mv file1 file2 dir1 dir2 submodule 
git commit -am "Moved file"

# Actually merging
cd myRepoRoot
git remote add sub url_to_submodule
git fetch sub
git merge sub/master
```

To explain it with words: you have several trees with no commit in common, and you just need to merge those trees. That's what the second part is doing.

The first part is just needed to ensure the filesystem of the submodule will be what you could expect.

Comment: I've modified a bit your solution - I've checked all the repositories to separate directories, removed submodules from main repository, moved files in submodules repositories (sibling directories to main repository directory), commited changes, in the main repository add 'remote' repositories as paths like "../submoduleA" etc and then fetched changes from this directories and merged them -- no need to push to remote repository.

Answer (score 3):

I've added an example based on the answer of @gturri, i hope it helps someone:

## Example

Let's say this is your submodule:

```bash
app/
├─ code/
│  ├─ Foo/
│  │  ├─ Bar/
│  │  │  ├─ .git/
│  │  │  ├─ .gitignore
│  │  │  ├─ registration.php
│  │  │  ├─ etc/
│  │  │  │  └─ modules.xml
│  │  │  ├─ view/
│  │  │  │  ├─ frontend/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ templates/
│  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ foo.phtml
```

Your submodule is stored in **app/code/Foo/Bar** and you need it to be in the exact location in the new repo, then do it like this:

```
# CD into the submodule
cd app/code/Foo/Bar

# Create the same directory tree as the current submodule path, in your submodule
mkdir -p app/code/Foo/Bar
```

---

> **Pro Tip**: Use `git submodule foreach 'mkdir -p "$sm_path"'` to automatically create the directory structure in all submodules.
>
> See [Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt)

---

New Directory added:

```bash
app/
├─ code/
│  ├─ Foo/
│  │  ├─ Bar/
│  │  │  ├─ .git/
│  │  │  ├─ .gitignore
│  │  │  ├─ registration.php
│  │  │  ├─ etc/
│  │  │  │  └─ modules.xml
│  │  │  ├─ view/
│  │  │  │  ├─ frontend/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ templates/
│  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ foo.phtml
│  │  │  ├─ app/
│  │  │  │  ├─ code/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ Foo/
│  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ Bar/
```

Move files to new folder via **GIT**:

```bash
git checkout <target_branch>
git pull
git mv .gitignore registration.php etc/ view/ app/code/Foo/Bar
git commit -am "Moved files"
git push
```

Now it looks like this:

```
app/
├─ code/
│  ├─ Foo/
│  │  ├─ Bar/
│  │  │  ├─ .git/
│  │  │  ├─ app/
│  │  │  │  ├─ code/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ Foo/
│  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ Bar/
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ .gitignore
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ registration.php
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ etc/
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  │  └─ modules.xml
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ view/
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ frontend/
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ templates/
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ foo.phtml
```

Delete submodule folder:

```bash
rm -rf <my_repo_root>/app/code/Foo/Bar
```

Merge your submodule to your repo:

```bash
cd myRepoRoot
git remote add sub <url_to_submodule>
git fetch sub
git merge sub/master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Remove submodule from repo (helps from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982/1539100)

```bash
rm -rf .git/modules/app/code/Foo/Bar
git config --remove-section submodule.app/code/Foo/Bar
```

Your submodule should now be located in your repository at `app/code/Foo/Bar`

Comment: I think you must use `--allow-unrelated-histories` as you can see in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37938036/1539100

Comment: and I think remove sub module with something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982/1539100

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. I had to entirely remove the submodule - using `git rm <path-to-submodule>` - before it allowed the merge. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982). I also had to use a local copy of the submodule as the remote, `git remote add sub ../localcopyofsubmodule`, as otherwise git-lfs absolutely refused to work.