# GitHub repository folder icon is black and not click-able

Tags: github, repository, git-commit

I am new to GitHub and finding it incredibly hard to learn.  I am following the instructions [here](http://kbroman.org/github_tutorial/) to create new repositories from an existing directory containing the project and typing `git init` ... etc.

However I created a repository in the wrong place and then deleted it by going into Settings at github.com.  Then, when I tried to re-push the files  the way I wanted it, one of the subfolders is now black (the one I had just deleted the repository for) and now not clickable - i.e. does not appear to be there.  See `statistics_project1` in screenshot below.

It's very hard to troubleshoot a problem like this.  There is no error message or explanatory text when you hover over the black sub-folder.

This post seems similar but I don't know.  The solution looks complicated.
[Cannot remove submodule from Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381530/cannot-remove-submodule-from-git-repo)

Could someone please tell me what a black 'unclickable' folder means in a github repository?[image]

Comment: could you paste your address of your repository where would find the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/basicmachines/statistics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the solution was a lot simpler.  The 'blackened' folder is in fact the old repo that was not properly removed locally.  As recommended by the author of the minimal tutorial I mentioned above, I simply removed the .git subdirectory which contains all git info and then re-pushed the repository to github.com and now everything is back to normal.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Cannot remove submodule from Git repo [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381530/cannot-remove-submodule-from-git-repo) had give the answers and steps to do if you have git installed.

"Via the page Git Submodule Tutorial:

To remove a submodule you need to:

1. Delete the relevant section from the .gitmodules file.
2. Stage the .gitmodules changes git add .gitmodules
3. Delete the relevant section from .git/config.
4. Run git rm --cached path_to_submodule (no trailing slash).
5. Run rm -rf .git/modules/path_to_submodule
6. Commit git commit -m "Removed submodule "
7. Delete the now untracked submodule files :rm -rf path_to_submodule"

copy from [remove a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule/1260982#1260982)

Comment: This sounds complicated.  Thanks but not sure I know enough about this to implement these instructions.  For example.  I don't understand what "Stage the .gitmodules changes git add .gitmodules" means.