# Git merge submodule into parent tree cleanly and preserving commit history

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repository with two submodules that I want to convert into a single project. Many answers involve scripts, and some seem to be overcomplicated.

```
[submodule "site"]
    path = wp-content/themes/site
    url = https://ajf-@bitbucket.org/ajf-/site.git
    fetchRecurseSubmodules = true
    ignore = all
[submodule "wpsite"]
    path = wp-content/themes/wpsite
    url = https://ajf-@bitbucket.org/ajf-/wpsite.git
    fetchRecurseSubmodules = true
    ignore = all
```

Is there an officially supported / documented way to merge these submodules into the parent repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [un-submodule a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759587/un-submodule-a-git-submodule)

Comment: Good article; https://medium.com/walkme-engineering/how-to-merge-a-git-submodule-into-its-main-repository-d83a215a319c

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The best approach is to do *subtree merging*.

First, remove the submodules and related configuration from your superproject; Edit your .gitmodules file to remove the submodules affected, or delete the file entirely if you intend to merge all submodules. Delete the submodule directories as well.

Next, add the submodule repositories as proper remotes to your superproject:

```
git remote add site https://ajf-@bitbucket.org/ajf-/site.git
git remote add wpsite https://ajf-@bitbucket.org/ajf-/wpsite.git
```

Then, fetch the remotes:

```
git fetch --all
```

Now, check out the branches that you want to graft to your main project from each sub-project:

```
git checkout -b site-branch site/some_branch
git checkout -b wpsite-branch wpsite/some_other_branch
```

After that, return to the `master` branch, or to the branch where you want to create the combined superproject:

```
git checkout master
```

If you want to create a (possibly temporary) extra branch for the operation, do this instead:

```
git checkout -b new-superproject master
```

You're now ready to merge the module branches as *subtrees* with your main project (in the `master` branch in this example):

```
git merge --strategy=ours --no-commit --allow-unrelated-histories site-branch
git read-tree --prefix=site/ -u site-branch
git commit -m "Merge 'site' from submodule"
```

Repeat this step for all branches created from the submodules. Check the final result with `gitk --all` or another history visualizer.

If you do not want to keep the history of the submodules, then only do the `read-tree` step and omit the `merge`/`commit` steps.

Since you want to convert into a single project, you're not going to update the subprojects independently, so I'm not going to describe how that works.

You can read up on this in the [chapter on advanced merging from Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging). Subtree merging is explained at the end of the chapter, but omits the step that creates a proper merge commit, so it will not preserve history of the submodule.

Comment: I had a problem with this method, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447457/git-read-tree-not-merging-commit-history

Comment: @AlainJacometForte: The question you link to is 410 Gone. (404ing).  Did you turn out to be mistaken?

Comment: @Navarr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759587/un-submodule-a-git-submodule maybe?

Comment: pretty elegant solution!

Comment: I think you should probably add 
`git checkout master`
prior to the read-tree step

Comment: Note that this answer (at least for me) does not preserve the history of the submodules.

Comment: @StephenHandley I have edited the post to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: I updated the answer to include a merge commit which will preserve history from the child repositories.

Answer (score 21):

A bit late to the party, but for those still looking for help, checkout these:

1. https://gitirc.eu/howto/using-merge-subtree.html
2. https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/about-git-subtree-merges

Below is a near verbatim copy of the first post:

```
1. git remote add -f Bproject /path/to/B
2. git merge --strategy=ours --no-commit --allow-unrelated-histories Bproject/master
3. git read-tree --prefix=dir-B/ -u Bproject/master
4. git commit -m "Merge B project as our subdirectory"

5. git pull -s subtree Bproject master
```

Explanation:

```
1. name the other project "Bproject", and fetch.
2. prepare for the later step to record the result as a merge.
3. read "master" branch of Bproject to the subdirectory "dir-B".
4. record the merge result.

5. pull in subsequent update from Bproject using "subtree" merge
```

As an alternative before step 4, you might want to update `.gitmodules` file, or just remove it:

```
3.1 git rm --cached .gitmodules
```

With this the history from the submodule is well preserved.

Comment: This is a very good answer. I should update my answer to reflect your suggestion of adding the `merge` step to preserve history.

Comment: This creates a subtree, instead of adding the history to the actual repository as a branch which is being merged in.

Answer (score 0):

Although the `merge` solution described in other answers works, it creates a single big merge commit which makes it difficult to track the submodule history.

Here is my alternative solution, which uses `rebase` instead of `merge` when merging the submodule. This solution is not as safe and straightforward as the `merge` solution, but in my opinion creates nicer history. Also, this solution may fail if you have file name conflicts between the parent and submodule repository (see the step 5 for details):

1. Name the submodule `Bproject` and fetch it to the parent repository:

   ```
   git remote add -f Bproject /path/to/B
   ```
2. Switch to the submodule:

   ```
   git checkout Bproject
   ```
3. (Optional) Filter the branch in order to preserve only files you want:

   ```
   git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter requested/subdirectory
   ```

   The command above filters `requested/subdirectory` subdirectory from the submodule and makes a new repository root from it. This step helped me to avoid conflicts of well-known files like `.gitignore` and `.gitmodules` by simply removing them from the submodule history.
4. (Optional) Move the submodule files to the future location in the parent repository. If the `Bproject` files are supposed to be located in the `src/Bproject` subdirectory, create that directory and move the files in.

   ```
   mkdir -p src/Bproject
   git mv *.* src/Bproject
   git commit -m "Move Bproject files to the src/Bproject subdirectory."
   ```

   After this step the repository looks like a "file system layer" which can be put over the `master` branch of the parent project.
5. Finally, rebase the `Bproject` branch over the `master` branch of the parent project. **This is the most critical step because it will work only if there are no file name conflicts between the `master` and `Bproject` branch.**

   ```
   git rebase --interactive master
   ```

   E.g. if you have a `README.md` file in the root of both repositories, this will certainly result in a rebase conflict. In this case, you have to either use optional step 3 to get rid of such file, resolve the conflict manually or just don't use the rebasing strategy and get back to the merge strategy.
6. If the rebasing went well, you can use `git log` to check the resulting Git history. You will see your `master` commits followed by the `Bproject` commits, and the commit dates will no longer be chronological. If you moved the `Bproject` files, don't forget to use `--follow` command-line switch to follow the file renaming.
7. If you are satisfied with the result, merge it to the `master` branch. You will get a trivial fast-forward merge without the merge commit:

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge Bproject
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did something simpler.

1. I entered the submodule repository and moved everything to a subdirectory.

   ```
   mkdir subdirectory
   git mv -k * .* subdirectory/
   git commit -am "Prepare to merge repositories"
   ```
2. I then went back to the parent repository, removed the submodule, committed and merged the child repository into it.

   ```
   git remote add submodule ../submodule
   git merge --allow-unrelated-histories submodule/master
   ```

And that's it. The history is perfect and everything is in a single repository.

Credit to https://medium.com/walkme-engineering/how-to-merge-a-git-submodule-into-its-main-repository-d83a215a319c