# Git submodule hash keeps causing conflicts

Tags: git, git-submodules

Everytime I make changes in the submodule, git registers the new commit in my original project

[image]

This causes loads of conflicts between different team members.
How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot simply prevent this. The commit hash of for your submodule is stored in a file, so if you change that commit hash in two branches of your super-project, then you will inevitably have a merge conflict.

If you need to change the submodule for every commit however, then maybe your submodule shouldn't have been a submodule in the first place. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327701/git-merge-submodule-into-parent-tree-cleanly-and-preserving-commit-history) on how to merge a submodule into the parent tree.

Also: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826715/how-do-i-manage-conflicts-with-git-submodules) on how to manage conflicts with submodules.

Comment: Cant that file be added to git-ignore somehow?