# git files not committing after .gitignore removed

Tags: git

I've created a new repository and committed everything, or so I thought.

I found that there was a `.gitignore` in my stylesheets directory.  I have removed this and did a `git add .` at the root of my project.  In the stylesheets directory I now have a `.git` file.

When I try to commit I get this:

```
git commit
    On branch master 
    Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   client/stylesheets (modified content)

no changes added to commit
```

How do I commit everything in the client/stylesheets directory?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions :)

Comment: Your `client/stylesheets/` directory appears to be a submodule. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah, I want to include `client/stylesheets/` and everything contained in it to be in my repository.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you also need the same directory to be usable from other repositories, or is it specific to this one?

Comment: This is is part of one repository which is only to be usable by this one specific repository.

Comment: I'm still not understanding. What does "part of one repository which is only to be usable by this one specific repository" mean? Do you need that directory to be a submodule (essentially a separate Git project inside your main one), or not?

Comment: Sorry, I just mean it should be part of this single repository like any other directory.  I don't know why it wasn't part of the initial commit, it should've been (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got nested Git repositories.

In general this is not permitted, though there are instances where it makes sense (e.g. when using submodules). You might have gotten into this state by accidentally running `git init` in a subdirectory, or by cloning into a subdirectory, or something else.

If you do not want to use submodules,

1. Look for an extraneous `.git` directory inside your `client/` directory or possibly in `client/stylesheets`. This is the internal Git repository; you may want to run `git log` or something on it to make sure you don't need it.

   If you're sure you don't need its history you can delete it.
2. Look for a file called `.gitmodules` in your main repository. If you find it, delete it.
3. If you found a `.gitmodules` file in the previous step, run `git rm --cached client` (or `client/stylesheets`, depending on where you found the `.git` directory).

Now you should be able to commit the directory as normal:

```
git add client
git commit
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1789374/354577) for more details.

Comment: That fixed it thank you.  I had to rm the `.git` file in the stylesheets dir and then `git rm --cashed client/stylesheets`  ...... adding and committing ran perfectly after that.  Thank you again :)