# Content of create-react-app is not pushed in github

Tags: reactjs, git, github

I pushed go & react codes to github.

Go codes are successfully commited but React codes are not.

React content is created by `create-react-app`.

```
article
├ api
│  └ main.go
└ client
   └ React content made by create-react-app
```

[image of github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sCk1.png)

Here is target github

https://github.com/jpskgc/article

I trid following command, but not solved.

```
error: the following file has staged content different from both the
file and the HEAD:
    client
(use -f to force removal)
$ git rm --cached client -f
rm 'client'
```

Also i tried following command, but issue is not solved

```
$ rm -rf client/.git
```

contents of client folder is to be commited in github.
but actually not committed.

Comment: What's the content of client?

Comment: Thansk reply.  The content is react.

Comment: run `git status` and post the log

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is both directories are git repositories in which case you would have a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).
You can see a submodule is added by this commit 
`Subproject commit 395ee793f20a65d483a50cb1d11b67e7f80729d0`.
To 
[remove git submodule but keep files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752481/remove-git-submodule-but-keep-files) follow this instructions.

```
mv client subfolder_tmp
git submodule deinit client
git rm --cached client
mv subfolder_tmp client
git add client
```

Comment: Thansk reply. I already tried `$ rm -rf client/.git` but this issue occurred.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit too late to come to this post. But in case anyone still wondering how to fix it. Here is what worked for me:

```
// moving to your client folder or whatever 
// the react-app folder is called
cd client
// remove the git in this folder
rm -rf client/.git
```

Now you go back to you root directory and do the add, commit, and push. You should have all your react-app folder pushed to the repository you want to.