# Add subproject as usual folder to repository

Tags: git, repository, git-submodules

I noticed that in my directory there were two modules that had been Subprojects of my Git repository. That happened because I moved them all to one Git repo and those modules (directories) had their own `.git` directory.

When I changed anything in those modules I would not see any changes in my main Git repository. I would see only this:

```
+Subproject commit e97ff0348e6adc697192ca4e6a367bdaeddcda6b-dirty
```

etc.

But I don't need that. I only need one Git repository without any subprojects. So I deleted `.git` directories inside those subprojects. And now I don't see any changes at all on my main repository.

I tried `add *` and `git init`. But it just does not see those directories even though it is inside repository. How can I make Git see those directories, so it would track their changes like other modules?

My Git repository looks something like this:

```
my_project/
 .git
 dir1
 dir2
 dir3 # Let's say this is the one directory that Git does not see. So any changes I make here are not tracked at all.
 ...
 ...
```

P.S. Those directories that are not tracked are not empty.

**Update**
If I rename that directory, then doing this:
`git diff`

I get this:

```
diff --git a/dir3 b/dir3
deleted file mode 160000
index e279fc4..0000000
--- a/dir3
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-Subproject commit e279fc481b9706ad79b24281efdbabd55179aee8
```

If I rename that directory back to original name, then doing `git diff`, returns nothing or just that there were no changes done.

Comment: Try to use git add -A / git add -all

Comment: Same thing. Does not see changes. When I try commit, it says nothing to commit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [un-submodule a git submodule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759587/un-submodule-a-git-submodule)

Comment: Related: here's my solution to this problem in general: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62368415/4561887.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After suggestion I looked at this: [un-submodule a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759587/un-submodule-a-git-submodule)

First tried:

```
git submodule deinit
```

After this it didn't change the old behavior. But when I did this:

```
git rm --cached yourSubmodule
```

Then it removed it as submodule and git started seeing those modules in main repository.

Comment: `git rm --cached yourSubmodule` is misleading, as you're not really removing a [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), but rather, just a directory containing another git repo. So, your example really should be `git rm --cached path/to/your/subrepo/dir`, no? And for your question specifically, since you mention `my_project/dir3` is the culprit, it really should just be this, right? `git rm --cached dir3`.

Comment: What you're really doing with `git rm --cached path/to/tracked/file` is stopping to track a file. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/4561887. In the case of a repo within a repo, git, by default, apparently tracks the entire sub-repo's directory as a single file which represents a directory. So, `git rm --cached path/to/your/subrepo/dir` just stops tracking that single file which represents the subrepo, & now, with its `.git` folder gone ([or just renamed, as I like to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62368415/4561887)), git will treat it like a normal directory next time you add it.

Comment: Its an old question, so dont remember. But probably yes.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows

1. Enable Hidden Files.
2. Identify the .git folder in the subfolders
3. Open Git Bash
4. Navigate to the folder where .git exists
5. Type the following command
   rm -rf .git
6. This will remove the .git folder
7. Now again stage, commit and push
   This worked for me