# Commit a subproject in a parent git repository

Tags: git

I have included in a javacript project another GitHub project. The first one is called prototype_threejswithoutReact and the second one is called Doodling.

I tried to commit the overall git repo after modyfing Doodling, and we see it is being saved as a Subproject:

[image]

I have read other threads: [Add subproject as usual folder to repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403278/add-subproject-as-usual-folder-to-repository)

And I decided to try to delete the child's .git, in Doodling. The result is that the IDE just knows that Doodling is into its parent prototype_ThreejswithoutReact, because we see that the branch in SourceTree and in the IDE match.

However I have tried to change Doodling's files but they do not show up in SourceTree to be committed.

***How could we commit Doodling's files?***

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try from a fresh cloned prototype_threejswithoutReact repo and:

- either add Doodling as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**

  ```
  git submodule add /usr/to/Doodling
  ```
- or, if you don't care about the history of Doodling, copy its content in a new folder within the parent repo (and add, and commit)

In both cases, that will be better than trying to fiddle with a nested Git repo (a subfolder with its own `.git/` folder in it) which would make the parent repo only records the root folder as a gitlink (special entry in the index, which is what you see)