# I uploaded a folder on GitHub. It is opening in Git, but not on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I pushed a folder to GitHub using 'git push' command. It is opening in my cloned directory. But when I try to access it on GitHub, it shows a different icon and doesn't open on clicking. Because of that, I am even not able to delete it. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: git only cares about files (not folders), what do you mean by "pushing a folder" ?

Comment: @topheman, furthermore `push` operates on *commits*, not files _or_ folders.

Comment: Does the "other icon" look like a grey folder?

Comment: Your question makes it glaring obvious that you have no experience in git whatsoever. There is a large number of tutorials out there, most notably the [*Pro Git* book](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control) or the [interactive git tutorial](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) from GitHub. You should take a look at these and try to understand the basics which should answer your questions perfectly.

Comment: @topheman, it was a folder containing the source code that i committed and pushed.

Comment: @melpomene, actually it is bitbucket repo and i can't give you access to it.

Comment: @Chris, yes exactly there is a grey folder of somewhat different shape than the normal folder. When i try to open it by clicking on it in Github, it doesn't give any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They grey icon you are seeing indicates [a *submodule*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules):

> Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your commits separate.

Submodules are often used for library code.

Based on [your Bitbucket comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112788/i-uploaded-a-folder-on-github-it-is-opening-in-git-but-not-on-github?noredirect=1#comment54052850_33112788) you are likely seeing this because you cloned another repository into your main one. Git repositories cannot be nested arbitrarily; there are extra workflow steps required.

It is possible to [convert a submodule to a regular directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759587/un-submodule-a-git-submodule), but before you rush down that path you should take a few minutes to learn what submodules are and see if they might be a good fit for your use case. There are real benefits to using them (e.g. the ability to work on the inner and outer repositories while still being able to `push` and `fetch` with the upstream repositories).

It's worth noting that some developers strongly dislike submodules (though in many cases this can be linked directly to a misunderstanding of how they work). There are other tools that let you do similar things, e.g. [`git subtree`](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/).

I think your next step should be to learn about your options (use submodules, use subtrees, or convert the inner repository into a regular directory). It's important to understand the tradeoffs of each before making a decision.

Answer (score 0):

One of the directories in the repository contained a '.git' folder. This folder is created in a directory whenever you run 'git init' command in it. A Git repository inside a Git repository confuses the Git and such a behaviour takes place.