# Upload files to Gitlab, but show as subproject

Tags: gitlab, git-commit, git-add

I tried to upload a folder `the_one_simulator` to Gitlab, but the folder is uploaded as a subproject, as shown below.

[image]

`the_one_simulator` was originally a repository in Bitbucket. I just copied it into `nc_ptn`, and ran the following command under `nc_ptn/`.

```
git add .
git commit -m "Add the ONE simulator"
git push -u origin master
```

How do I upload all files under `the_one_simulator` to Gitlab?

I deleted `the_one_simulator/.git/`, and tried `git add .`, but encountered the following issue,

```
$ git add .
Assertion failed: (item->nowildcard_len <= item->len && item->prefix <= item->len), function prefix_pathspec, file pathspec.c, line 317.
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question on SO where `gyim` answered the question wonderfully. See their answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1789374/5385187 This should give you all the information you need to make the submodule a regular directory and commit the files to the top-level repository.