# Possible to merge wear and mobile Git repositories

Tags: git, android-studio

I've been developing an Android Wear project ("RefWatch") using Android Studio for about 18 months. I noticed about 6 months in that the git repositories for the project are actually in two directories:
`/Users/<name>/AndroidStudioProjects/RefWatch/mobile` (the mobile module)
AND
`/Users/<name>/AndroidStudioProjects/RefWatch` (the wear module and everything else)

I don't know whether this was an accident when I created the Android Studio Project, but Android Studio seems to do an ok job of commits/checkouts to the separate repositories.

Where I run into trouble is:

- I want to branch my code; this always seems to create a detached HEAD
- If I want to use command line commands I seem to have to browse each repository separately
- I want to push everything to BitBucket or some other remote

So, questions:

1. Is this "two .git" directories actually normal or ok? Is it designed this way?
2. Is there a way of merging the two .git repositories to simplify my life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mobile module was likely added as a [Git Submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).  This is completely reasonable, and may or may not be what you actually want to do.

If you're using a submodule, you will have to manage each repository separately, which includes browsing the history, committing, pushing to a remote, or running other Git commands.

If you want the mobile module to have a separate release cycle from the main project, and/or if you will be reusing it in other projects, then you should leave it as a submodule.  Otherwise, it should be fine to merge the repos.

To merge the the submodule into the main repo, do:

```
mv mobile mobile-tmp
git submodule deinit mobile
git rm mobile
mv mobile-tmp mobile
git add mobile
```

(From [VonC's answer to "un-submodule a git submodule"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162228/2747593).)