# How to make a commit to the nested repository?

Tags: git, git-submodules, dotfiles, prezto

I've cloned the [skwp/dotfiles](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles.git) to use as my own dotfiles.
Time to time I have been making commits to my dotfiles for the improvement purposes. Mostly these commits were made to main part of repository.

Now I need to make commit to `~/.zshrc` file. This file belongs to [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) repository which is submodule of [skwp/dotfiles](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles.git) repository.

The question is how I can make this nested repository as part of my dotfiles? Should I change the remote url to point to my repository? Or is there a way to integrate the [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) to one big repository, and then I can make commits to repository seamlessly no matter which part of repository to push commits to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep `prezto` as a submodule, but change its URL to point to a fork of that repo that you own.
Meaning, you need to fork https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto.git, and then change the URL seen in the [`skwp/dotfiles/.gitmodules`](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/blob/master/.gitmodules) file: see "[Changing remote repository for a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675130/6309)".
From there, you can make any new commit you want in that submodule, add, commit and push (to your fork), then go back to the main parent repo, add, commit and push (also to your fork).

The other approach, still assuming you have forked the main dotfile repo, would be to un-submodule the `prezto` submdule: see "[un-submodule a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759587/6309)".