# Git add and commit is not adding files

Tags: git

I apologize if this is a newbie question, but I've been search around and I'm dumbfounded as to why this is.

I have some files I'd like to add and commit.

I run:

`git add .`  I also tried `git add -A`, `git add -f -A`

`git commit -m 'message'`

`git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit master origin/master temp` (to make sure my master branch is on the latest commit)

`git push origin master`

Yet there are no changes.  The push was successful.  But the files are not being added to my repository.  What could be the reason?

EDIT:

I should mention that Git doesn't seem to be detecting new files.  When I specify the exact file to add, such as `git add myapp/newFile.html`.  I get an error message `fatal: pathspec 'myapp/newFile.html' did not match any files.`  The file is clearly in the folder.

EDIT 2:

I tried re-making my folder with `rm -rf .git` and then re-doing all the steps.  But when I do `git add -A` again, the new files are still not being added!  My folder feels like it's cursed or something.

EDIT 3:

Results from `ls -la`

```
drwxr-xr-x 0 valachio valachio   512 Jan 11 20:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 0 valachio valachio   512 Jan 11 20:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x 0 valachio valachio   512 Jan 11 19:43 bungol
drwxrwxrwx 0 valachio valachio   512 Jan 11 19:43 config
drwxrwxrwx 0 valachio valachio   512 Jan 11 20:41 .git
-rwxrwxrwx 1 valachio valachio   804 Jan 11 19:43 manage.py
drwxrwxrwx 0 valachio valachio   512 Jan 11 19:43 misc (non-coding related stuff)
-rwxrwxrwx 1 valachio valachio   327 Jan 11 19:15 Pipfile
-rwxrwxrwx 1 valachio valachio 13798 Jan 11 19:43 Pipfile.lock
-rwxrwxrwx 1 valachio valachio    38 Jan 11 19:15 Procfile
-rwxrwxrwx 1 valachio valachio   115 Jan 11 20:08 README.md
-rwxrwxrwx 1 valachio valachio   368 Jan 11 19:43 requirements.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 valachio valachio    12 Jan 11 19:43 runtime.txt
drwxr-xr-x 0 valachio valachio   512 Jan 11 19:43 staticfiles
```

Results from `git ls-tree HEAD`

```
100755 blob a0994e0c2c674f7964b97e73bf8b639e0bd15fa3    Pipfile
100755 blob 79baf37feb267b9479d4b8979623e9164d8d17c3    Pipfile.lock
100755 blob 2a05d1701bb03f8e565ccb53b5048a2ecbb8ea81    Procfile
100755 blob 0fa4a27c2e5a6e03c3edf2eb096766c20c0e9206    README.md
040000 tree c1179776614cf441fd04a5241b91869e3b24a776    bungol
040000 tree 8f0028f91df90b5124315f5e1cdd776c55fe2300    config
100755 blob 68141ee9e00d47db18f3598190234e8f8818dd5d    manage.py
040000 tree 4209dc1c056f595660ebf39ed57dc5bf72841597    misc (non-coding related stuff)
100755 blob d108cb2bdc916228474253e8c014dd1944df27f2    requirements.txt
100755 blob 5f61493782f81ae7c642d97051a8be79da5b7dba    runtime.txt
040000 tree a044a50441ede0a7718934b096f3c11ef4e5c2ae    staticfiles
```

EDIT 4:

I found the problem.  I am using Ubuntu and the new files did not have access permissions.  I had to give the current user access permissions to those new files with `chmod 755` and after that it works.

Sorry I didn't mention this in the original question.  Thank you to everyone that provided answers.

Comment: Can you post the output of `git status`, before and after running `git add *` ?

Comment: Do you have a `.gitignore` file that may be excluding the files you want to add?

Comment: what if you `git add myapp` ?

Comment: @JoshuaD I get the following - `On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: Please show the results of these three commands `ls -la` and `git ls-tree HEAD` and `cat .gitignore`

Comment: After you did `git commit -m 'message'` what output did you see?

Comment: @JoshuaD Added.  Doing `cat .gitignore` gives me `cat: .gitignore: No such file or directory`

Comment: More commands to try and add the output to your question: `git log` and `git reflog`.

Comment: Also, which new files are you attempting to add?

Comment: All of the files which show in `ls -la` are also shown in `git ls-tree HEAD`. This means that all of those files have been committed to git. What are you seeing that makes you think that the files aren't added?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice When I check my repository after the commit finishes, the new files are not there.  Also when I set up a fresh new folder and did `git add .`, the new files are still not being added.

Comment: Which repository are you checking and how are you checking it?

Comment: Are you on branch master? That's the only branch you're pushing up to ghithub. `git branch` to see what branch you're on.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm using Heroku and also a GitHub repo so I can do `git push heroku master` or `git push origin master` and I can check both places to see that the files were not committed.  I can see the log when I do `git add -A` that the new files aren't being added.  So it's something wrong with `git add`

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I found the problem.  It was a file permissions issue with Ubuntu.  Once I gave the current user permissions to the new files, it worked fine.  I should've mentioned this in my original question.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's clarify a few concepts of git:

1. Your local directory is a git repository. All git commands interact with the local repository in some way. Some commands also interact with a remote repository
2. `git add .` will all files in the current directory to the staging area of your local repository. Whenever you do this, **git will always add the files** because this is how git works. Note that "adding" files only stages them for the next `git commit`.
3. `git commit` creates a commit in your local git repository with the files that you have previously added to the staging area. Again, this command will always do this. In fact, the output from `git ls-files` in your post proves that all of your files have been added and committed to your local repository.
4. Your local repo can be connected to remote repo on GitHub or any other sever running git. If you do `git clone`, your local repo will have a remote named `origin` which points to the repo which you cloned. If you do `git init` instead, you can use `git remote add` to add a remote with whatever name you wish.
5. Once you have a remote repo configured in your local repo, you can use `git push` to push commits from your local repo to the remote one. Likewise, `git pull` will pull commits from the remote to your local repo.

Answer (score 1):

Try `git add *` and `git add .*`.

Comment: `git add *` has no effect.  `git add .*` gives me the following error - `fatal: ..: '..' is outside repository`

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn’t detect changes then you could start over. Simple delete your .git file from the directory and reinitialize again. This might not be a good practice but if you’re new in git then sometimes this kind of fix helps.

Also make sure your user access credentials are setup correctly.

Comment: I did that.  I also tried to start the project in a completely new folder.  All the old files were added and committed fine.  But the new files are not being added.

Comment: Ok just to make sure that you have a git repo. So you remove the .git from the directory. Then you do git init. And then you git remote add origin your-git-name. Have you done all these steps?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can arise on freshly cloned projects. Don't forget to check if this repository uses **Git Submodules a.k.a. nested reps**. No matter how many times you `git add -A && git commit`; as an extra step you will have to **navigate to the nested folder and commit there too**. Only then, you will finally get a nice and clear `git status` output.

On a side note, I you don't want this submodule and you one to track everything from the parent repository you can refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759990/11239755