# Git: Push a local git submodule, including submodule files, to a remote bare repository

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-remote, git-bare

I have two local projects which I manage with `git`, one being dependent on the other – like this:

```
project A/
├── project B/     
│   ├── file B₁
│   ├── file B₂
│   ├── …
```

It makes sense to me to have `project B` as a git submodule of `project A`.

Now, I have set up a remote *bare* repository for `project A` for backup and sharing purposes. Of course, I want the remote repository to contain all of `project B`, including its files (`file B₁`, `file B₂`, …). But `git push` and `git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand` don’t achieve this. Whenever I list the files in my remote repository by `git ls-tree -r HEAD`, only the files of `project A` itself are listed. This *does* make sense to me.

However, is there a way to push the entire submodule `project B` to my remote base repository somehow, preferably in a clean way?

Answer (score 0):

A submodule has to have a separate repository. Create a new bare repo and push your submodule to it.

Answer (score 0):

If B is actually a submodule, you should have a .gitmodule referencing it.
In that `.gitmodule` file, you would see the remote repo URL where B is pushed, in case there is any new commits done in B.

But B being a submodule means A won't have B files in it, only a *reference* to B SHA1.

If you want, you can un-submodule B (with [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162228/6309) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43554035/6309)) in order to keep all the B files in A.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately submodule exists like SHA-1 code in parent module.so you should archive with another way:

1. `mkdir tmp_a && cd tmp_a`
2. `git init && git remote add origin http://your/repo.git`
3. `cd .. && rsync -a ./project_A/ ./tmp_a/ --exclude='*.git*'`
4. `git add . && git commit -m"some log" && git push --set-upstream origin master`

That works well