# Include contents of submodule in main repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've run into a peculiar situation. I have a main repository with remote1. This main repository has a sub repository within it with remote2. I would like to track the contents of the sub repository in the main repository ignoring the fact that sub repository exists i.e. as if `.git` folder in the sub repository didn't exist. Is it possible to do this? If yes, how?

Comment: Don't use submodules, they are not a good fit for what you want to do. Use `git subtree`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58969776/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/59077584/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+track+submodule+main+repository