# How can I git clone a repository with submodules as only a single repository?

Tags: git

Imagine that I have a git repository called `foo` and I want to clone it into another directory named `bar`.

What I normally could do, assuming that `foo` is already cloned somewhere on-disk, is this:

```
git clone foo bar
```

And that will clone `foo` into `bar`. But if `foo` has submodules, then `bar` will not get the files in those submodules. Normally, you'd want to use `git clone --recursive foo bar` to add those submodule files over. That will clone the repository, its submodules, and each submodule's refs into `bar`.

However this is actually **not** what I am looking for. I don't want `bar` to contain any submodules, just the files from `foo`. Since `foo` is cloned locally this seemed possible but I don't see in git clone's documentation about how to do it. Is there a way to do what I'm looking for in a (ideally single) command?

Comment: There *are* ways to do this, but they basically replay all the commits generating new hashes.  So you'll end up incompatible in git terms with everyone using the original repo; in a pinch you could still trade email-style raw diff patches, but unless you have something *extremely valuable* and *concise* to contribute they'll probably make you create your own fork of their repo with its submodules intact, re-apply your patches there, and then generate compatible pull requests from that...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [un-submodule a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759587/un-submodule-a-git-submodule)

Comment: Especially read and carefully evaluate the answer there offering "git-submodule-rewrite"