# How to transform a submodule to an embedded repository

Tags: git-submodules

I used to have a git repository (`sub`) inside of a git repository (`main`). I was happy. But, one sad day, in a spark of over-engineering fever, I decided to turn it into a submodule. Now I want to get back to the good old times: transform the submodule back to a simple subfolder, with the history of that project being tracked in the `sub/.git` directory instead of having it in the main repository’s `.git/modules/sub` folder. How can I do that?

`git rm --cached sub` and `git submodule deinit` both keep the history into `.git/modules/sub` instead of moving it to `sub/.git`. [This question about un-submoduling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759587) differs from mine as it wants to integrate the submodule history into the main repository’s history, whereas I want to keep them separate.  Reading the answers about [removing a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1260748), I also could not find how to keep the history of the submodule and transfer it to the embedded repository rather than losing it altogether.

Note that I do not want to push the history of `sub` entirely to its corresponding remote: I want to keep some branches local (for confidentiality reasons). So, the local history of `sub` is precious. I can’t simply delete everything related to `sub` from `main` and clone from the remote again (plus, fetching from the network what I already have locally would be inelegant, I’d rather avoid it unless it simplifies the process a lot).

I want to do this for simplicity reasons and because I do not want to keep a reference to a specific “current” commit of `sub` in `main`. Currently, each time I move the `master` branch forward in `sub`, `main` will realize that something has changed into the submodule and annoy me about updating the submodule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if `.git/modules/sub` can be renamed as `sub/.git`

You will have to edit the new `sub/.git/config` file, in order to remove the `core.worktree` setting.

But you should see your full sub history there.