# Permanently merge a git repo to a main repo, keeping history

Tags: git, merge

We have a main repo `Core` where we maintain libraries we use in many projects.

I was developing a library in a separate repo `ErrorHandling`, that I now want to permanently merge to `Core`, while keeping the commit history.

Is this possible?

Comment: Would this solution meet your needs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

Comment: I thought it would first, but when I read about the solution (subtree merge) it doesn't seem like a permanent solution. To clarify: I want to merge, then **delete `ErrorHandling`**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import existing GIT repository into another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another)

Comment: Not really a duplicate. And if it is, please explain how I can apply it to my problem

Comment: Just did a [Subtree merge](http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html), and sure enough, the directory is there. But the history doesn't seem to be merged, if I check `git log`.

Comment: When you say you "want to permanently merge to Core", could you explain *where* in your repo it will merge? That is, is it going to look like Core/ErrorHandling, or something else? If the former, the solution presented in [How to import existing GIT repository into another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another) should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, the subtree merge described in "[How to import existing GIT repository into another?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8396318/6309)", based on GitHub article "[Working with subtree merge](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-subtree-merge)", is a bit more complete than the [basic subtree merge presented in the Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html) (mainly the `git merge -s ours` step).

```
git remote add errorHandlingRepo server:errorHandling.git
git fetch errorHandlingRepo 
git merge -s ours --no-commit errorHandlingRepo /master
git read-tree --prefix=errorHandling/ -u errorHandlingRepo/master
git commit -m "Imported errorHandling as a subtree."
```

> You can track upstream changes like so:

```
 git pull -s subtree errorHandlingRepo master
```