# import local git repo to remote server repo

Tags: git

*Update - known issue with git-enterprise. Used unfuddle and [subtree merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html) works now*

I've been developing locally only on my machine using Git. It has never been pushed to a remote repo.

I just signed up for an account on enterprise git. I now want to import my local repo to the newly created remote git repo and maintain the history.

Tried to follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another), though receive

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

So then tried

```
git clone repourl/project.git
cd project
git remote add other /tmp/myproject
git checkout master
git commit
git push
```

When I did git commit received

```
On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Doing git push receive

```
Everything up-to-date
```

Though if I do "ls" I see all my files.
If I do "git log" I see my version history.

Comment: How are you pushing your local repo?  What command gives you the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to github and bitbucket private repo. enterprise-git too buggy at least when I was trying

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a simple push do the job?

Here is what I think is needed:

1. Add the enterprise git as a remote to your existing local repo(which has all the data).
2. Then a `git push <enterprise-remote-name> <branch-name>` will push the specified branch on your local repo to the enterprise repo, will all it's commit history.

I haven't used enterprise git, but I use github everyday and the above two steps will do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone looks for a solution when you're also in charge of the remote server: Init the server's repository with `git init --bare` instead of just `git init`.

Comment: then I start getting `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree` when trying to work with remote