# How to add one git repository into another git repository's sub-folder?

Tags: git

I have one GIT repository in a folder called **AA**, and I have second GIT repository called **BB**.

I want to import the **AA** repository into the **BB** repository as a sub folder.

before:

```
AA
 |- .git
 |-  A/
 |-  fileA

BB
 |- .git
 |-  B/
 |-  fileB
```

after:

```
BB
 |- .git # new .git with both AA and BB .git infos
 |-  B/
 |-  fileB
 |-  AA/      # <== no .git anymore
 |-  AA/A/
 |-  AA/fileA
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another?rq=1) what you are looking for?

Comment: Similar but not exact. I have tried solutions mentioned there, folder structure is different.

Comment: Do you still need the history of AA?

Comment: Look for "subtree merging". I dont have time to write out a whole answer right now, but that should pretty much get you there, it does exactly what you want. Lets see... maybe [this github article](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-subtree-merge) will give you some first pointers

Comment: @NevikRehnel, [subtree merging](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-subtree-merge) is exactly right. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If folder structure is different a `git mv` would solve that:

1. Clone the orig repo,
2. `git mv` all stuff into a new subdir `AA`.
3. Then use that as the source repo to clone from with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8396318/923794) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1683531/923794).