# git (python/django repo) merge challenge (original repo copied to another repo) now need to merge it back

Tags: django, git, git-merge

I have a git repo at repo1URL.git.  It's a production repo and I didn't want to mess with it (in hindsight it would have been easier to just create a branch in that repo!).

It's a django app that is very poorly structured (with third party libs added as folders, rather than via virtualenv and pip.

I made a physical copy and deleted the .git folder of the copy, created a new repo at repo1URL-changes.git and added it as a new remote into the copy.  Cleaned up things by removing unnecessary folder, etc, and pushed it to the new repo.

Now I'd like to merge those changes into the main production repo.  I found the following question: [how to import existing git repo into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another)

I followed the instruction @ [Selected Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another?answertab=votes#tab-top).  But the results of the:

```
git merge ZZZ
```

is rather a nightmare!  With conflicts even on .png files and almost every other file.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Perhaps you could apply in order the commits of the new repo to the old repo?

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn good idea!  How can I do that?