# Git Merge two repositories that are years apart with thousands of conflicts

Tags: git, merge, repository, branch, fork

**Repository A:** The old fork we're working on now, but with hundreds of recent commits based on 3-year-old code from B. The history is long gone - it only goes back a few months when the repository was first uploaded to Github.

**Repository B:** The new, current one we don't have access to. Years of history. Would like to keep updated with it's Master branch when finished.

At some point ~3 years ago, repository A was a fork of B and then never kept up-to-date with B. We'd like to change that. We want to be Repository B with all of our changes from A.

The pseudocode of what I think needs to happen:

1. Clone B into a new project with a [Master] branch.
2. Make an [Old] branch containing all of A.
3. Merge [Old] branch into [Master] branch and fix thousands of conflicts (How would we keep history from A?)
4. Set up an Upstream remote for Repo B in order to keep up-to-date from now on.

I'm hoping for some advice, clarification, and/or a translation of the above pseudocode and how it might work.

Thanks!

Comment: "Clone B into a new project ..." How, if B is the "new, current one **we don't have access to**"?

Comment: B is the original repository that A was forked from. It's the "main" project we're building A from.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, what you want to do is quite simple; the only complicating factor is the sheer number of expected conflicts. One thing you can do to mitigate that is to try merging older commits from `B` into `A` first. Say that after you `git clone B Blocal`, you have something like this:

```
*---......-----*  A/master

*---......-----*  Blocal/master
```

Instead of trying to merge `B/master` into `A/master` all in one go, merge in small chunks.

```
git remote add Blocal
git fetch
git merge  <some old commit in Blocal/master>
```

which, after fixing potentially many fewer conflicts, you'll have

```
           M1
*--...---*-* A/master
          /
*--....--*--...........................--* Blocal/master
```

where `M1` here (and `Mi` in general below`) is a merge commit.

Then, repeat with a slightly newer commit in `Blocal/master`.

```
           M1         M2
*--...---*-*--------*-* A/master
          /          /
*--....--*--......--*--.....................--* Blocal/master
```

Keep this up, with a chuck of `Blocal/master` at a time, until you can finally run

```
git merge Blocal/master
```

to get something like

```
           M1         M2       M3          Mn
*--...---*-*--------*-*--..--*-*--.....--*-* A/master
          /          /        /           /
*--....--*--......--*--................--* Blocal/master
```

This way, you don't have to deal with all the merge conflicts at once. You may be able to, by examining `Blocal/master`' history, find good places to do merges that result in fewer merge conflicts.

Once you've completed the merge, you can set `A/master` to track the real `B` instead of your local clone.

```
git branch --track B/master
```

Answer (score 1):

You might end up with an import similar to the situation in [How to import existing Git repository into another?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1683531/47392).

Sounds to me like you want to to something like Jörg suggests in his answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1684435/47392) which is actually based on Linus Torvald's "[Coolest Merge EVER](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/5126/)".