# Replace branch in git repo from with another branch with changes history

Tags: git, github

For example, I have a git repo called **Parser** with a branch called **Production**.
Then, there is a repo called **ReParser** with **master** branch.

I need to replace **Parser/Production** with **Reparser/master**, both files AND commit history. How can I do this?

Comment: Wouldn’t [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another) work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Parser` repo.

```
$ git add remote reparser <reparser/repo/url>  # add a new remote named reparser
$ git fetch reparser                         # sync with 'reparser'

$ git checkout master                        # checkout to master
$ git branch -D Production                   # delete existing local 'production' branch
$ git checkout -b Production                 # create and checkout 'new production'

$ git pull reparser master                   # replace parser/Production with reparser/master
$ git push -f origin HEAD                    # force push to remote Production of Parser
```