# EGit: combine two git repositories for the same project

Tags: eclipse, git

Scenario: Project was stored in a git repository created by EGit of Eclipse. Later on my development machine was broken. So I took the backup Eclipse project and imported it (the project, not the git repository) in a new development machine. On the new development host I created a new git repository with the imported project as the initial commit of the new git repository.The new git repository has the exactly same project name as the old one contains. Both have one branch which is the master.

So I lost the history of the commits on my old development host. Is there any way that I can combine the two with all the history from the old and new repositories? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import existing Git repository into another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another)

Comment: @CMZS Did you push your `old repo` to `remote`?