# Git: "could not read from remote repository", when remote is another local repo

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I’m working in my local copy of a repository `AAA`, and I have added another local repository `BBB` as a remote `bbb`.
Specifically, I’ve tried adding it with each of

```
git remote add bbb ../../Path/to/BBB
git remote add bbb ../../Path/to/BBB/
git remote add bbb ../../Path/to/BBB/.git
```

However, with any of those, when I issue

```
git fetch bbb
```

it fails with error message

```
fatal: '../../Path/to/BBB' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The given path really is the root directory of a repository: if I issue

```
cd ../../Path/to/BBB
git status
```

git quite happily tells me about the status there.  What could I be doing wrong?

(Background: I’m following the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1684694) for merging BBB into AAA.)