# Git Subtree merge not showing history

Tags: git, merge, git-subtree

I'm trying to merge one repository into another, as a subdirectory. The goal is to keep the history.

I've tried the top 3 methods here: [How to import existing Git repository into another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another)

While they all complete successfully, when I do a `git log myfile` I only ever see my merge commit. I never see the full history of the file. However, if I do a `git blame myfile` I see all changes.

Maybe I don't understand the subtree merges, but shouldn't I see all the history for a file afterwards?

Comment: Does `git log --follow -- myfile` work?  I'm thinking that the most recent change to the file may be moving it to a new path

Comment: `git log --follow -- myfile` gives me no output. Straight `git log -- myfile` gives me my one single commit.