# How to add one repository to another repository on Github?

Tags: android, git, github, repository

How to add one repository to another repository on Github? I have one project workspace XXX and i have my own created repository YYY somewhere else, so i want to add that repo to that blank repo created.

Comment: Anything apart from this? https://gist.github.com/martinbuberl/b58fd967f271f32f51f50aee62e7332c

Comment: You can pull project from first source then you can push to second source

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import existing Git repository into another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another)

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple way I can think of

1. Clone the xxx repository
2. open it and delete `.git` folder
3. open terminal and type `git init`
4. type command `git remote add origin GIT_URL_OF_YYY`
5. add , commit and push

Comment: Any idea how to manage/best practice of keeping the multiple repositories(Microservices) in GitHub

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to use [git submodules.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

So within workspace XXX, adding YY would be:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/YY
```

See the example in the git submodules link for more.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with simple two steps :

1. clone {current}
2. push {new}

---

A. [clone](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-clone) {current} `git clone`

1. create local directory
2. open terminal
3. `git clone ssh://john@example.com/path/to/my-project.git`
4. `cd my-project`

B. [push](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-push) {new} `git push <remote> <branch>`

1. `git remote add origin example.com/path/to/my-project.git`
2. `git push origin master`

   - you may face an error of repo{s} timing, so.. you may need to fore pushing
   - and you may face some other problems then you will just run `git add .` `git commit -m "first lanuch"` `git push -u origin master`