# How do I pull just one folder from another Git repository?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm creating a monorepo from some existing repos, and I want to preserve the commit history.

[This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32684503/1068446) tells us that the `git subtree` command is good for this, and it works fine if we want to import the old git repos as is to the new structure.

However, the I have one project I'm important that looks like this:

```
/
  server/
    index.js
    package.json
  src/
  package.json
```

Here, I want to import just the `server` folder, and retain the commit history on it.

I could just import the whole folder, delete everthing I don't need, and then shift everthing in `server` up one folder, but I'm worried about destroying the commit history.

Is there a way to import just a sub directory?

Comment: you can create a branch in your project and then 'filter-branch' the subdirectory of interest. Import the branch then.

Comment: Thanks @Serge - That was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Serge suggests in the comments - [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) can be used to achieve this.

Here's the way I did it, perhaps there's an easier way to do it.

1. Create a temporary remote repo 'temp'.
2. In existing repo:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter server -- --all 
git remote add temp git@temporaryrepo....
git push temp master
```

This will create a repo with everything inside the `server` directory as the root.

3. In your new repo

```
git subtree add -P packages/server /path/to/temp.git master
```

This will import the temp root into `packages/server`