# Understand git-filter-branch usage with update-index

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I've been trying to decipher the `git-filter-branch` command used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43345686/3656081) to rewrite the index such that all the repo contents are within a new directory, which is then used to move this to the subdirectory of another repo. Focussing on the specific command:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter '
        git ls-files -s |
        sed "s,\t,&'"$dir"'/," |
        GIT_INDEX_FILE="$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" git update-index --index-info &&
        mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
    ' HEAD
```

This essentially seems to change the index to look from `/folder1/path/to/file` to `'newrootfolder'/folder1/path/to/file`.

Questions:

- Where is the `GIT_INDEX_FILE` variable coming from, what is it set to and how does that entire line work?
- How does the new folder(say `newrootfolder`) get automatically created in the repository  - does git internally detect and create the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GIT_INDEX_FILE` is one of the [repository environment variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_repository_locations)

> the path to the index file (non-bare repositories only).

That filter command and example was [introduced in June 2007](https://public-inbox.org/git/Pine.LNX.4.64.0706211504060.4059@racer.site/T/#u), with [this patch](https://public-inbox.org/git/Pine.LNX.4.64.0706211805010.4059@racer.site/T/#u)

```
GIT_INDEX_FILE="$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" git update-index --index-info
```

That part forces git to re-create a new index file, with the renamed folder in it.

```
mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
```

Once the new index is created, it can replace the legacy one.

---

Please note the current option (in python, so cross-platform) is to use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which replaces the [old obsolete `git filter-branch` or BFG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309)

```
git filter-repo --path <olddirectory>/ --path-rename <olddirectory>/:<newdirectory>/
```

Example:

> If you want two directories to be renamed (and maybe merged if both are renamed to the same location), use `--path-rename`; for example, to rename both `cmds/` and `src/scripts/` to `tools/`:
>
> ```
> git filter-repo --path-rename cmds:tools --path-rename src/scripts/:tools/
> ```

Comment: Thanks, for this specific task I needed to use `git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter ${dir}`. Also would be great for completeness sake to explain how the entire command in the question is working, especially the 2nd half.

Comment: @tangy I agree. I have edited the answer to add some explanation about the second part of the old `git filter-branch` command.